# Is self-promotional question tagging allowed? If not, how do you handle it?

Tags: discussion, tags, spam

Not really sure where to bring this up but I was watching the pending-edit queue and noticed a user by an eponymous handle retrospectively tagging some seemingly contrived questions with the following:

[ithit-webdav-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ithit-webdav-server) [ithit-ajax-file-browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ithit-ajax-file-browser) - some example posts: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23064528/does-it-hit-ajax-file-browser-is-using-flash-silverlight-or-java-for-files-uplo), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290840/how-do-i-get-rid-of-authentication-login-dialog-when-opening-ms-office-docs-from), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21772487/what-is-the-maximum-upload-file-size-for-it-hit-webdav-server-engine), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746994/how-do-i-return-error-message-from-webdav-server), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20632098/do-i-need-to-run-it-hit-webdav-server-msi-on-my-windows-server)

... notably all questions by the same user or users with low rep - which might go some way to explaining the unusual up-votes given the poor quality of the original posts.  "IT Hit" is also a commercial entity.

Other than flagging these questions for being off-topic / not following the guidelines - what's the procedure here?  Should I be untagging these posts?  Would it generally be acceptable if they were of higher quality?

Comment: Tip, please use more descriptive titles whenever possible. "Is this kind of activity allowable" is very vague. ***What kind of activity*** are you talking about?

Comment: true enough - didn't consider the post might have future value.

Comment: @Emissary: Any post that doesn't have future value should not be posted. :) _[Disclaimer: since this is Meta, I'm pretty much lying.]_

Comment: See also: [Is it acceptable to use Stack Overflow as a Q&A for a specific product?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253849/456814), and [Third-party development support: hosted by Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253394/456814).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

In the future, the best way to handle is to:

- Flag a post the user has edited; and explain why you're flagging

  > This user seems to be retagging questions with an inappropriate tag (ithit-webdav-server)
  >   It also appears this user is involved in a lot of posts that the ithit account is, there   may be something there)

Try not to get into a rollback/edit war.  Editing to remove it is fine, but it's an even better move to let us know, in case there turns out to be more to it.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see anything wrong with this, other than the fact the tag isn't very useful. It's certainly not inappropriate as the OP has up-front declared that this is the technology he's using.

The fact that it's the guy who writes the software who's doing the tagging doesn't seem particularly relevant in this case. Not to me, anyway. This isn't like those cases where promotion occurs on barely-or-not-at-all relevant questions, trying to gain new customers.

Comment: I probably wouldn't have been as concerned if the questions had any substance - tags are supposed to help folks find quality information and without having all the facts it struck me that the users may have been the same person - in which case it's a little underhanded?

Comment: @Emissary: Oh well if one of those accounts is a sockpuppet of the other then certainly so.