# Is adding company name tags spam/vandalism?

Tags: discussion, tags, spam

I noticed this morning (UK time) that I'm being asked to review a large number of edits where a user has added the tag "componentone" to anything that currently has the tag "grapecity" and vice versa.

Here's an example of one such edited question:

[How would I differentiate from Click and Double Click while using a C1FlexGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320124/how-would-i-differentiate-from-click-and-double-click-while-using-a-c1flexgrid)

Reading around, ComponentOne produce a suite of UI controls and a company called GrapeCity have bought them. Their products are still sold under the ComponentOne banner.

It seems to me that someone is being paid to trawl StackOverflow and add these owning-company secondary tags to everything they can. This feels rather like spam to me. For instance, I wouldn't expect anybody to add a "Microsoft" tag to every C# question.

As someone who is not familiar with those tools, I'm not sure how relevant those additional tags are, so I have skipped a number of them. However, I was wondering - should I be flagging such edits as spam?

Comment: The tags don't add any value, it appears; noone but the company itself would follow that tag, I'd wager. I'd just burninate the tags, no need to go flag it as spam just yet.

Comment: There might be a minor case to make for the ComponentOne tag (not sure though), but GrapeCity not so much.

Comment: I've asked the user to stop the edits for now and informed him about this question. He seems to have stopped, so perhaps we can see what was valid, what was invalid, and how we can best proceed. I don't think this really classifies as spam or vandalism. Misguided perhaps.

Comment: Sorry about tagging. I was trying to make the branching of tags constructive. I suppose it is one thing to do for your convenience and another for the users. BTW is there any provision under stack api where I may follow these tags collectively under one tag?

Comment: Tags don't form a hierarchy @NilayVishwakarma, so if you're looking to follow a group of tags under a certain common parent, that is not possible.

Comment: That was my thinking - individually, they mostly seemed either irrelevant or too minor. It was more the sustained campaign of editing every post relating to one of their products that was concerning me.

Comment: So it seems I should follow/subscribe a list of tags and work on them  separately.

Comment: Related (highly): `(1)` [Is self-promotional question tagging allowed? If not, how do you handle it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253144/456814), `(2)` [Third-party development support: hosted by Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253394/456814), and `(3)` [Is it acceptable to use Stack Overflow as a Q&A for a specific product?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253849/456814).

Answer (score 48):

In general, we prefer product tags to company tags.

Company tags don't tell us anything about the content of the question; they are therefore considered meta tags.  The proof: any question that would be asked about *a company* on Stack Overflow would most likely be off-topic.

**Further Reading**
[The Death of Meta Tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags)

Comment: well, I guess the question OP had remains - "should I be flagging such edits as spam?"