# Should we burninate the [jetbrains] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

*The Phase #2 of the burnination process described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070), is completed and it has been decided that the tag should NOT be removed from the system ([status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)), but instead renamed to a more specific tag-name*

---

(I'm noticing a trend of these "Do we [really]* need" type of questions, but...)

I came across the [jetbrains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetbrains) tag when editing a question. It, in and of itself, is only a company - and any question tagged with it seems to be associated directly to the products it produces (ReSharper, IntelliJ IDEA, RubyMine, WebStorm, et. al.).

My gut feeling is to purge this tag.  Questions that are tagged with this alone can't stand on their own, since they would be asking about the company, not any of the specific products.

[**EDIT**]  To reply to some of the remarks being made as justifications for keeping the tag:

My judging criteria is based on [The Death of Meta Tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/), specifically this excerpt:

> 1. **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.** Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective], and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they tell you nothing at all about the content of the question.

Bearing that in mind, I look again at the questions tagged with [jetbrains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetbrains) and try to think why they would be able to stand on their own if they were *only* tagged with that.

Thing is, they **can't**.

All questions that are also tagged with Jetbrains are also tagged with the more specific (and appropriate) product tag with which the question is concerned with.  This is why I feel strongly about burninating this particular tag.

Furthermore, not that I wish to go on a tangent or go outside of the scope of this request, but perhaps we should look into other company-specific meta tags as well.  If the tags really *can't* stand on their own (that is, a question tagged with just that isn't considered on topic), why are we keeping them around?

[**EDIT #2**]  To assuage any fears that this is going to make it inconvenient to find specific JetBrains products, take a look at [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/129835/number-of-questions-tagged-with-jetbrains):

```
Tag                Count TimesMoreQuestions
------------------ ----- ------------------ 
intellij-idea      22749 2068.09090909091
pycharm            5141  467.363636363636
teamcity           4693  426.636363636364
phpstorm           4485  407.727272727273
resharper          4045  367.727272727273
webstorm           3067  278.818181818182
rubymine           1022  92.9090909090909
teamcity-9.0       300   27.2727272727273
teamcity-8.0       222   20.1818181818182
intellij-idea-14   194   17.6363636363636
teamcity-7.0       123   11.1818181818182
resharper-8.0      103   9.36363636363636
resharper-6.0      89    8.09090909090909
resharper-7.1      75    6.81818181818182
teamcity-7.1       74    6.72727272727273
resharper-9.0      67    6.09090909090909
rubymine-7         55    5
phpstorm-2017.1    52    4.72727272727273
intellij-idea-2016 47    4.27272727272727
resharper-5.0      47    4.27272727272727
teamcity-9.1       36    3.27272727272727
resharper-6.1      31    2.81818181818182
resharper-plugins  29    2.63636363636364
resharper-10.0     26    2.36363636363636
resharper-4.5      24    2.18181818181818
resharper-sdk      23    2.09090909090909
phpstorm-2016.1    22    2
resharper-5.1      21    1.90909090909091
teamcity-10        21    1.90909090909091
teamcity-5.1       21    1.90909090909091
resharper-2016     20    1.81818181818182
intellij-idea-15   19    1.72727272727273
resharper-7.0      18    1.63636363636364
teamcity-5.0       18    1.63636363636364
teamcity-6         16    1.45454545454545
phpstorm-2016.3    16    1.45454545454545
resharper-8.1      13    1.18181818181818
resharper-9.1      12    1.09090909090909
resharper-c++      12    1.09090909090909
resharper-5.x      11    1
resharper-9.2      10    0.909090909090909
resharper-8.2      9     0.818181818181818
teamcity-rest-api  7     0.636363636363636
phpstorm-2017.2    5     0.454545454545455
phpstorm-10        4     0.363636363636364
resharper-2017     4     0.363636363636364
phpstorm-8         2     0.181818181818182
phpstorm-9         1     0.0909090909090909
phpstorm-5         1     0.0909090909090909
phpstorm-7         1     0.0909090909090909
teamcity-4         1     0.0909090909090909
```

I'm not convinced that the removal of this meta tag would be negative, considering how comparatively few questions are tagged with [jetbrains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetbrains) AND something else.  Furthermore, if they wanted a specific version of any of their products, then they could specify that.

[**EDIT #3**]  Seems like there's some moderator consensus about [company tags in general](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253910/1079354):

> In general, we prefer product tags to company tags.
>
> Company tags don't tell us anything about the content of the question;
> they are therefore considered meta tags. The proof: any question that
> would be asked about a company on Stack Overflow would most likely be
> off-topic.

I'll be marching on with this burnination, along with cleaning questions up along the way.

Comment: This is a candidate for blacklisting, since, if it's burned, it will just come back.

Comment: There are many of these tags. I disagree completely with this. Why remove it, is there a benefit to removing it? No. It only becomes harder for jetbrains employees to find these questions. Removing things because we don't _need_ them is stupid if they serve a useful purpose. We don't *need* badges, but they're useful. So we keep them.

Comment: @Jhawinsss:  How could it be harder for them?  They know *exactly* what products they have in the wild.  Stackoverflow has a tag for them all (and the ones that *don't* have a tag should have that tag created).  I see absolutely no problem in forcing specific tags to be used instead of the omni-tag.  What's worse, there's **way** more questions tagged with specific products than there is with the jetbrains tag.

Comment: @Makoto you didn't address the part about removing things for no reason. I'd like to know what negative consequences exist due to this tag. If none exist, or they don't outweigh the benefits of it, I say it stays. Why change things if there's no benefit?

Comment: @Jhawinsss: [It's a meta tag.  Meta tags are explicitly discouraged.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)  They lure unsuspecting users into believing that these types of tags are useful or have merit.

Comment: I don't see why this is a meta tag. It certainly could be the only tag on a question about a JetBrains product. It is adequately descriptive.

Comment: @CodyGray:  In what way is it adequately descriptive?  There are already tags about the individual Jetbrains products out there; why do I need the all-encompassing company tag to describe the problem I'm having?  Could you provide an example in which a question tagged with Jetbrains alone is adequately descriptive of a question, without that question being wildly off-topic?

Comment: @Makoto A Jetbrains tag to my Q here would be enough, since it's not actually strictly related to a specific product, but *all* of their IDEs. http://stackoverflow.com/q/17484123/923847

Comment: @Matsemann:  I'm not sold on that.  Although I see your point, if you solve the issue in one specific IDE, then you will have solved it in all IDEs.  My argument would be to tag it with the specific IDEs that you're encountering this in.  This way, you get the generic scoping that you should have on a question (it relates to these five IDEs which happen to behave virtually the same), and you also get the right people looking at the question sooner.  From the SEDE query I did above, there's really not a lot of traction with the tag; it by itself pales in comparison to a specific IDE's tag.

Comment: I think your quote of Jeffs post is a bit out of context. He also says that "I don’t really have a problem with [hidden-features]. Seeing that tag on a question, I *KNOW* what I will get when I click on it. Compare with [best-practices], or [subjective], or [beginner], where the meaning is basically a mirror held up to whoever you ask at the time: in other words, random." - you know what you get with `jetbrains` tag, something related to jetbrains products.

Comment: @eis:  My argument is, if you're talking about a Jetbrains product, then you should be talking about a *specific* Jetbrains product.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +65/-22. A1 (Saying No): +58/-27. A2 (Neutral?): +8/-8. A3 (Saying No) +4/-7. A4 (Saying No): +21/-5.

Comment: The point in edit3 is moot, as it is not used as a company tag, but as an *umbrella tag* for a lot of similar products.

Comment: How did you get that opinion @Matsemann? [I see many posts on the first page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9BOL.png), which are very incompatible technologies

Comment: If I had a question about my workflow in IntelliJ IDEA, CLion and PyCharm; that might apply to other Jetbrains IDEs, but I personally only use those 3 IDEs, how should I tag that question?

Comment: @snooze92 if you have such a question, probably you should narrow down to the actual problem.

Comment: @Braiam It's not his fault if the problem actually does exist across the common Jetbrains IDE code base, which many issues do. This tag should be preserved, or else we'll exceed the tag limit adding tags for each affected IDE for such questions: `jetbrains` is much clearer than `idea webstorm clion pycharm  phpstorm`.

Comment: @Jeremy that "exist across the code base" isn't the same as "I'm having a problem with X". There are issues affecting the underlying library, but as a user, those things shouldn't matter to you.

Comment: @Braiam This isn't hypothetical. I have worked in companies where we used multiple JetBrains IDEs on the team, and experienced issues affecting several of them at once. Perhaps not five, but three, yes. It's not the end of the world, but it would look silly on a question.

Comment: @Jeremy afaik, from the users perspective, while it may affect different products the same way, you can't be completely sure. I use dbeaver as sql client, which in turn uses Eclipse. There might be something that affects both the same way, but as a Dbeaver user it's a dbeaver issue, not a Eclipse one. That's the product which the bug report would be attached. If I have a question about dbeaver, I will look for answers that apply to dbeaver.

Comment: I'd be leaving this featured for some more time, as there seems to be more answers trickling in (which is really great!). @Makoto, you've added some good points  in the comments of the question, as well as on the answers... would it be possible to collect them all into an answer, so that it'd help me tally the scores at the end? Thanks. (As of now, the balance is tilted towards not burning the tag).

Comment: @BhargavRao:  I'll put it on my to-do list for ~6 hours from now.

Comment: @Braiam Trying to think of an example question, let's say I wanted to change the default position of the Terminal tab for new projects, in all 3 IDEs. Would I ask 3 times, once per IDE? Or ask for those 3 in one question and use 3 tags? Just to be clear; I am not arguing one way or another, only trying to clarify what is proposed.

Comment: Then you would have to burninate other tags, too...

Comment: If you don't like this tag - don't use it

Comment: I wonder what would happen if tomorrow Jetbrains decided to launch a new IDE that does **not** use the same core code/IDE. Will we then modify `jetbrains` or `jetbrains-ide` to `jetbrains-intellij-idea-ides`?

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +171/-55 A1 (Saying No): +170/-68. A2 (Neutral?): +33/-20. A3 (Saying No) +7/-11. A4 (Saying Retag): +135/-14. A5 (Saying Yes): +19/-22. A6 (Saying No) +7/-23. A7 (Saying No) +30/-6. A8 (Saying Yes) +2/-2. A9 (Saying Disambiguate) +2/0. The community has voted to keep the tag, but rename it as [jetbrains-ide] (A4 -> top answer, least controversial, most score rise since featuring).

Comment: ... has reached a point where manually tallying the scores has become cumbersome. :-( ... happy that there are more users chiming in, though. :-)

Comment: I'll second the sentiment about more users chiming in, I changed my opinion based on the additional feedback during the tail end of the featured period.  (Naturally after it was too late to rescind my initial votes on several early answers.)

Comment: "It, in and of itself, is only a company" Someone let `amazon` know.

Answer (score 146):

I agree it's not optimal. But in this case, a lot of Jetbrains' products share the same core. So a question about PhpStorm may apply to RubyMine, IntelliJ IDEA etc. What tag the question is tagged with just happens to be the specific product used by the asker.

I often search for `jetbrains <what I'm wondering>` instead of `phpstorm <what I'm wondering>`, as I get more answers that way, and they still apply to my situation.

An example of this is [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484123/how-to-not-have-inspections-and-language-injections-in-diff-makes-identical-cod). It related to **all** IDEs by Jetbrains. I just tagged it with the two that I use and a commmon Jetbrains tag.

I suggest renaming the tag to **jetbrains-ide**. It wouldn't be a meta-tag, as it could be tagged on most of the questions now tagged with a specific IDE, since it applies to all of them. And then it's not a company tag.

Comment: Except: No question I saw on a quick review of this tag is specifc to common functionality. But when we argue on this base, at least we need to use `jetbrains-ide`. But it's still a burnination, since we can not simple rename it. Some questions are also tagged with [`dottrace`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55365089/dottrace-is-it-possible-to-change-profiling-type-ie-from-sampling-to-tracing-wi) for example.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt actually, burnination is just the final state of the tag, not the process itself. As long as the tag doesn't exist at the end, burnination is completed. The method, manual removal, renaming, disambiguating, is irrelevant.

Comment: Not sure which point you are trying to make. My point is, that the tag souldn't exits anymore at the end, therefore I would call it *burnination*. [See this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/2441442). @Braiam

Comment: I agree, [jetbrains] sounds off-topic, but [jetbrains-ide] does not. All of their IDEs are basically the same product. If they wanted to, they could have made a single installer like Visual Studio where you install only the components you need, but I guess that it doesn't fit their pricing model, and that being able to download independent binaries has other advantages.

Comment: @Dalmas how are all of their IDE's are same? All of their [softwares](https://www.jetbrains.com/products.html) are very well crafted and different from each other, i've been using them for some time and they are all not the same

Comment: @window.document: Not identical, but they do share a common design, and some interfaces (e.g. plugin system).

Comment: I can easily imagine looking for an answer to PhpStorm and finding it in a question asking about WebStorm.  Two VERY similar products sharing a common core; the crossover is useful

Comment: That's why `jetbrains-ide` sounds like a good solution for the tag

Answer (score 114):

Helping employees of a small company to find the questions that they can help with is useful.

And it is working.  The top-rated answerer in this tag is [CrazyCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104891/crazycoder).  A Jetbrains employee.

There's precedent as well, [devexpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devexpress) has a tag and team members that have answered questions.  [telerik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/telerik) has one.  [installshield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/installshield) has one.  [sap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sap) has one.  [componentone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/componentone) has one.  [redgate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/redgate) has one.  Etcetera.

Let's not make it hard for them, there's just no point.  And lets not single-out just [jetbrains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetbrains), that would be grossly unfair.

Comment: Let's not forget [microsoft] [apple] [google]...

Comment: I disagree.  I'm also noticing that this precedent is a little disturbing - we're allowing meta tags because it makes finding questions to answer in regards to that company easier?  How about, instead, the individual product tags be used to find specific questions to answer?  I take this approach to a tag - it has to be able to stand up on its own, as if it were unattached to anything.  What questions that are specific to Jetbrains would fall on topic here at SO?  Tangentially, what questions that are specific to the other company tags would be on topic as well?

Comment: I disagreee too. As Jetbrains etc have product tags that they could create an OR filter for: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17008/153036

Comment: Looking at these tags they either need some *serious* cleanup or, in my opinion, should be completely removed. They're misused, not used consistently and add *nothing* of value to the tag ecosystem. Additionally, a tag should be able to stand on its own, without any other tags...that's not the case for these.

Comment: @Makoto This answer makes sense to me. A person *can* be an expert in a company's products. They most likely work for that company. Tags are more about finding questions than answer, given the tooling StackOverflow provides.

Comment: @BoltClock all these tags are gone now. We should do the same for [jetbrains]

Comment: @VadimKotov by the way, when I see the list of associated tags, i see lots of redundats tag with version, those are usually removed now too, except some case where it is really necessary.

Comment: SO supports tag-wildcard searches like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/teamcity*+or+intellij* etc.; this argument of "easier to find questions" doesn't hold any water for me.  (Maybe it did in 2013 if monitoring activity or new questions in multiple tags in one browser tab was harder back then.) I could see an argument for making it possible to get a gold badge more quickly in a common tag, allowing more experts (especially employees) to duphammer. The case for searching needs to be made much more strongly, because we're talking about searching by people who know their way around SO

Comment: Although if jetBrains try to search questions on stackoverflow with the jetbrains tag only, they'll miss out on question that are tagged with specific idle's name that they have, just like what we did for microsoft, apple tags, we should burninate it for the company's good

Comment: I think we should see the views of @CrazyCoder and see what he says about this

Comment: They can use search operators.

Comment: @BoltClock said the reel thing. We don't have a tag for microsoft only, we have [microsoft-teams], [microsoft-edge] but NOT [microsoft]. So why is JetBrains any different ? Or better ? Or exceptional ? Same rules apply for all companies in here. Burninate this tag.

Comment: @AntoinePelletier: If we had Microsoft employees whose job is to answer questions on stackoverflow like jetbrains is clearly doing I'd say what the hey we can tolerate it.

Comment: I don't buy it. Does a single support person want to look for every platform their company makes? I doubt it. Support staff in every company I've ever worked at only cover a few platforms each. That user has 21x more votes in the `intellij-idea` tag. He's clearly looking at that specific tag more than he's looking at `jetbrains`.

Comment: @Joshua Are you saying that we don't have Microsoft employees whose job is to answer questions on stackoverflow like jetbrains is clearly doing? I've seen Microsoft employees answer C# questions, and they don't need a Microsoft tag

Answer (score 27):

## TL;DR; There are product specific as well as Jetbrains-wide things at hand.

We should not burninate the Jetbrains tag, because many things are general to the Jetbrains products.

These questions are not product specific:

- [How to make phpstorm display line numbers by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8086023/576767)
- [Jenkinsfile syntax highlighting in PyCharm Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51124878/576767)
- [Can I configure JetBrains Toolbox to automatically update IDEs when new versions are released?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54950797/576767)

And the first one was duplicated as well when tagged python, whereas the answer is **the same**, not similar, or lookalike, the actual same:

- [How to make PyCharm always show line numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10187228/576767)

It makes no sense to remove the jetbrains tag and force a product specific tag on these questions, that have the same answer for all the products.

---

As someone who uses multiple different Jetbrains ides on a daily basis, I believe it most definitely should **stay**. Contrarily to some comments, **most questions are not product specific**. The settings are widely the same, the way to configure live templates, macros, plugins is widely the same, actually, the product themselves say a lot less about anything I do with the IDE than the fact that it is a Jetbrains product.

Most of the questions I've had, were answered not while reading questions that were tagged with the specific product I was using. The exception is when I find a question tagged with the same IDE' not the rule.

I'm not sure where in the process we are, but don't forbid the tag to be used, this is a move that would only hinder the findability of questions and answers.

---

I think there is some confusion. The settings are not alike. They are the *same* except for what is only relevant to the language, which is not the majority of what is exposed in these IDE. Here is the general settings panel across Pycharm, Webstorm, PHPStorm and CLion. In there, more than half of the options are the same, "Appearance & Behavior", "Keymap", "Version Control", "Build, Execution, Deployment", they offer the same functionality.

[image: Pycharm settings]
[image: Webstorm settings]
[image: PHPStorm settings]
[image: Clion settings]

It's not only the same top level, it's not only the same feel, **they offer the same functionality**, this is the javascript language configuration across Pycharm and CLion:

[image: Pycharm javascript language config]
[image: CLion javascript config]

Here is the debugging screen from the Build, Execution and Deployment in Pycharm and Webstorm:

[image: Pycharm debugger]
[image: Webstorm debugger]

And here it is for CLion. We can see that the top level menu also have a few things that are only relevant to the language:

[image: CLion debugger]

## These are not similar. They are exactly the same.

They offer configuration over the same things, are used in the same way across the products, and if a question about any of those were tagged as any specific product it would have to be tagged with all products as well.

---

Here is the live template configuration screen in clion and webstorm:

[image: CLion live template]
[image: Webstorm live template]

The only thing that differs is the syntax of the language being used, **everything else, from context choosing, use of variable in the template, all is exactly the same**.

Comment: I see your point about the live templates, but I disagree; it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to create a Java-centric live template in Rider, for instance.  I would espouse a tag for jetbrains-live-templates, as that's more descriptive and *would* expose questions and answers for that.

Comment: @Makoto The only (only) thing that differ in live template creation, is the syntax of the language being used. Everything else, the way to put variables in the live template, the way to invoke them, choose a context, is exactly the same.

Comment: So let me be sure that I'm on the same page with you here.  You're saying that, because the *settings* for the IDE are similar, that there should be precisely one tag available to describe them.  In my mind, this ignores other aspects of the IDEs, such as actually configuring projects or setting up the debugger in each of them, since *that* would be different between them all.  Additionally, there are limitations on what can be configured in each IDE.

Comment: I won't disagree that there are similarities between the IDEs and their configuration.  Heck, the key bindings are likely the same as well.  However, that would ignore context and would make it harder to find actual experts who know a specific IDE's layout to help a user with that *specific* problem (e.g. someone who's worked in Rider but has never heard of CLion would be burned by a common tag like this).

Comment: No, I am saying that there should be a general Jetbrains, or jetbrains-ide, tag, that can be used if the issue is general, and product specific tags, when the isse is actually product specific. Burninating Jetbrains tag and or preventing a general tag is a mistake, as it will force specific tags on jetbrains general issues.

Comment: Could you find some examples of these sorts of questions *today* which would be negatively impacted by this burnination then?

Comment: @Makoto here https://stackoverflow.com/q/54950797/576767 also here https://stackoverflow.com/q/51124878/576767 also here https://stackoverflow.com/q/8086023/576767. Those three questions are not at all only specific to their products.

Comment: @Makoto Two of the highest voted jetbrains questions are actually duplicates that were asked because they tagged differently, whereas the answers are the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187228/how-to-make-pycharm-always-show-line-numbers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086023/how-to-make-phpstorm-display-line-numbers-by-default

Comment: Those are fair examples (I did create the new [tag:jetbrains-toolbox] tag to help with questions about the Toolbox going forward), and I do see your point.  I think that there could be two parts to this; if we're talking about *generic* functionality, then we could allow a jetbrains-ide tag; if we're talking about *specific* functionality, we could require the specific IDE.  I wonder if there's a way to get that to be done by the system...I think they did it for VB.

Comment: .. thank you for putting up with my rather high excitation about the issue. I just feel very strongly compelled to protest the disparition of the tag. I'll go walk around my cubicle now.

Comment: Thanks for fighting the good fight @FélixGagnon-Grenier, I completely agree with your stance

Comment: Honestly @FélixGagnon-Grenier, I'm just happy I could find a stronger argument for the tag.  I would argue, however, that this calls for disambiguation anyway, since there are common questions which span all IDEs but don't require the "jetbrains" tag moniker.  I feel like something more specific or pointed could actually be useful here as opposed to what looks like a company tag (which prompted this request some years ago).

Comment: Your argument is that the IDEs are sufficiently similar such that there are many questions which span all of the IDEs. Then, wouldn't it be better to have a tag that is [tag:jetbrains-ide] rather than a tag that is about the company (i.e. [tag:jetbrains])? In other words, a product-line based tag, not a company based tag. So, shouldn't what's applied to the current tag be both a disambiguation/clean-up along with renaming the [tag:jetbrains] tag to [tag:jetbrains-ide]?

Comment: @Makyen I don't see the problem with using Jetbrains for that, and leave that to the more capable hands of experienced people in these burnination processes. As long as there is a general tag that can be applied to questions that are not product related, but rather jetbrains related. Yes, jetbrains-ide could be it!

Comment: Why we are comparing jetbrain ides with other jetbrain ides? A user will never have problem with the interface of an ide but instead of the language he's using in that ide and for that the user should use specific tag, the purpose of tag is not to group questions but rather to [describe the topic of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) so it tells about the question, also _The only thing that differs is the syntax of the language being used_ is not true as we haven't dwell into the source code of each and every ide, they must have different compilers for different languages?

Comment: @window.document "A user will never have problem with the interface of an ide but instead of the language he's using in that ide and for that the user should use specific tag" You are wrong, the highest voted questions are about the line numbers, which is not specific to the language being used. please look at the links I put at the top of the answer, these are not related to a specific product.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier They are settings related questions not programming related questions and are asked rarely, what if i was using [teamcity,](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)[youtrack,](https://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/) etc,. They all have different interfaces and if questions are to be asked regarding them then specific tags are to be used, the tag [jetbrains] just doesn't add any meaningful information to the question, It can be any product any one of all the 21 products the have, if i watch the tag and i only know php, .NET can come in my feed

Comment: @window.document Reality contradicts you. they are not asked rarely. Please consult the [jetbrains] tag on main. There are multiple, valid, highly voted questions, that are not related to a specific product, and they are totally on-topic, as tools commonly used by developpers. As Makyen said, maybe jetbrains-ide would be more valid, but it most definitely is not good to simply remove it. Again, **please read the questions I linked**, they are on-topic, and not relevant to a single product. a jetbrains or jetbrains-ide is relevant on them.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier even if i agree with you there, you should not forget the purpose of tags on Stackoverflow, please [see the link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) I shared in my comment about tags, yes a jetbrains or jetbrains-ide is relevant on them but it lacks to describe the topic of the question like if it's phpstorm, .NET etc.,

Comment: @window.document I am fairly aware of the purpose of tags... thank you. A question should not be tagged phpstorm if it's not about phpstorm, right? The line numbers in the jetbrains-ide are **not** about phpstorm. They are about the jetbrains ides.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier [the answers in the question about line numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086023/how-to-make-phpstorm-display-line-numbers-by-default) that you mentioned in your question is also working same for android studio as i just tested it as android studio is built on JetBrains' IntelliJ IDEA, that's why we have a tag called android-studio which is being widely used as we speak, we don't use google or jetbrains for questions related to android studio.

Comment: @window.document So, you would like to have a question about line numbers for every single one of these products? One for android studio, one for phpstorm, one for pycharm, one for clion etc forever? What is it that you propose then? Jetbrains, or jetbrains-ide to be more specific, is totally fine to represent the range of questions we are talking about.

Comment: And actually, what's wrong with having the jetbrains tag along the android studio one here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/21181847/576767. They are both valid, although both jetbrains (or jetbrains-ide) or android-studio by themselves would have been fine.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier what i meant with my previous comment is that if there's a question related to android studio's settings, then we would tag it with [android-studio] not with [google] [already burninated] or [jetbrains], same as with the IDEs of jetbrains.

Comment: Reality, once again, contradicts you @window.document. Questions tagged both jetbrains and android-studio exist, by the dozens. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetbrains+android-studio. it's interesting that the owner of an account two months old speaks with so much certainty about this. Did you bother verifying any of your claims or? Like, how come you did not make that search about the tags before saying we would not tag like this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191046/discussion-between-felix-gagnon-grenier-and-window-document).

Answer (score 14):

From Makoto's comment:

> "How about, instead, the individual product tags be used to find
>   specific questions to answer"

Most of Jetbrains products use a common code base which means that some bug reports and most features and feature requests will actually apply to all of their products at once.

> "Questions that are tagged with this alone can't stand on their own"

Which is not really relevant to whether a tag should exist or not; tags are there to help people find similar or related questions, they don't need to be completely descriptive without reference to anything else.

Comment: A common code base isn't justification for a company specific tag.  If I have a question about PyCharm, then I'd better ask it with a PyCharm tag, or I won't get all relative experts in the IDE looking at it.

Comment: "tags are there to help people find similar or related questions" - Just... no. Tags are meant to categorize questions into areas of expertise. That statement would effectively validate the use of every meta-tag that has ever existed.

Comment: @animuson yes, because a question about Python tagged [tag:beginner] bares striking resemblance to a question regarding Assembly on a 4004 also tagged [tag:beginner]... No

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place for a company's feature requests.

Comment: @Makoto No, a common codebase is not, but the **same configuration panel across all product, with the same editor configuration options everywhere** is. A question about how to configure formatting refactoring, or indentation options, will be the same for all products. The macro creation, live templating, most of the actual actions are the same within all ides.

Comment: I don't see this as anything resembling a "beginner" tag or the like. JetBrains is its own ecosystem, with scads of common code and common interfaces across apps.  It totally makes sense to have the tag to encompass all of their products at once.

Answer (score 4):

To compile some thoughts on the discussion I've had with others on the matter:

[Per Felix](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382289/1079354), there are other questions which do fit under the general umbrella of JetBrains IDEs.  To wit, this has been the *only* convincing argument which stands in front of burnination.

There are other problems with this - we now have questions which pertain to the JetBrains Toolbox which need to be disambiguated from the [jetbrains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetbrains) tag, and it would do well to disambiguate questions which are about a *specific* IDE from the generic IDE.

New proposal:

- Disambiguate the [jetbrains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetbrains) tag from any IDE-specific concern or question.
- Use the [jetbrains-toolbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetbrains-toolbox) tag where and when appropriate to address questions about the JetBrains Toolbox utility.
- Rename the tag to something less about the company and more about the tool in question - maybe [jetbrains-ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetbrains-ide).

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. We need to retag the questions [here with jetbrains-toolbox](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjetbrains%5D+%22toolbox%22&mixed=0) and we should be done with the cleanup.

Comment: Third bullet point is done.

Comment: @BhargavRao why did you use status-declined? The tag doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @BhargavRao:  Second bullet point is done.  A handful of the questions in that list mentioned that they installed the tool via the Toolbox but weren't about the toolbox in any other way.

Comment: @Braiam:  It's a synonym now.

Comment: @Braiam, That is the norm for any tag where it was decided that the tag should not burninated. (A quick check for "tag should NOT be removed from the system" would confirm that).

Answer (score 0):

The questions should not be tagged with `jetbrain` when using a JetBrains technology, in the same way you do not tag with `microsoft` a question regarding Visual Studio or .Net.

To the rest of the counterarguments:

> There are employees of JetBrains that answer the `jetbrains` tag.

They should be following the tags according to each of the individual product on which they want to provide answers on.

> There are more JetBrains products sharing the same codebase.

This is just the design choice that they adopted. In this case a common tag could be found for these products if needed, but not keeping a tag for all of the products that they have.

Besides these two arguments, I see a lot of subjective answers which are pro keeping `jetbrains` tag, but which are not fair for the rest of the *companies* that do not have a dedicated tag.

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, burn it.

Some argue, jetbrains IDE products are all based on the IntelliJ Plattform, and therefore it is possible to ask a question about the core functionality. But seeing many tags like [resharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resharper) or [teamcity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/teamcity), [jetbrains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetbrains) is simple the wrong tag for it. Even if we create a tag like `intelij-like-ide`, I don't think there is any benefit to it. Every question I saw on a quick review regarding an IDE, it was language/framework specific and doesn't ask about the common functionality. And even when we create a common IDE tag, we still need to go through the burnination procedure, since we can not simple rename it (because of the many different tools).

Thinking further: ReSharper and many more Visual Studio products are based on the [Resharper Plattform](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/sdk/Intro/ReSharperPlatform.html). I would expect a tag for this, if some developer is developing against it's api, but not if a developer needs support in [resharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resharper) or [dottrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dottrace).

Some argue it helps the company to find questions to there products: Then they should simple use the specific tags as favourite or search. As a Resharper user I don't care about IntelliJ or Teamcity.

I also tag all my ASP.NET Core Questions with [asp.net-core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-core) and not [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft). And I expect you do the same. And it has a reason. Why should the reason here different?

So I argue, it is a [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/), which can not stand on its own.

So yes, burninate it.

---

Just some view [from the first page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetbrains?sort=newest), to proof my point, the tag has many different (not related) technolgoies:

[image: Different Products]

We want to ask about the technology, and not about the company.

Comment: Top one is a poor example, the WebStorm codebase is wholly included inside PHPStorm, and so that question applies also to PHPStorm users, however if they search "phpstorm react interpolation autocomplete", they may struggle to find a result as opposed to "jetbrains react interpolation autocomplete"

Comment: Except this burnination request is about jetbrains and not web/phpstorm. The fully integrated part is what I mean with above core functionality. Still Webstorm is not integrated in Teamcity, Resharper, Dottrace, Dotmemory etc.

Comment: My point was simply that you stated: "Every question I saw on a quick review regarding an IDE, it was language/framework specific and doesn't ask about the common functionality.", but the first example from your screenshot is about functionality common between at least two of the IDEs, what would you suggest it be tagged with?

Answer (score -9):

Use case for this tag.

Problem was: which plugin was causing my IDE to no longer recognize keyboard input in the main editor window? Classic Stack question -> a little too obscure, a little too specific, a little too generic. Have you seen JetBrains' bugtracking site? Not really intended for anybody who isn't keenly intereseted in picking up tickets - it's so full of information I don't need that finding the one ticket I'm hoping for was pointless - it took forever to find, and it didn't answer my question anyway. I ended up having to disable all fifty kajillion plugins I use in the name of getting back to work. Ish. I can't debug, but at least I can type. :(

I also feel like the JetBrains tag stands alone in the sense that for plugin dev, they share the common base and while their usage varies somewhat by stack, most of them are available in multiple products. A question like, "Node listener not connecting," needs the JB tag, and nothing else - no ambiguity, and it doesn't matter if I'm in PHPStorm, WebStorm or PyCharm.

So, yeah. Moral of my story is people are using this tag as tags are intended to be used. :)

Comment: That doesn't sound like it belongs in the scope of Stackoverflow *at all*.  It's not a question specific to developing a plugin, but rather, a support-esque question.  Jetbrains' YouTrack is **perfect** for that question.  Stackoverflow, much much less so.  I wouldn't be opposed to a plugin that asked pointed questions on developing an IntelliJ/Ruby Mine/ReSharper/PyCharm plugin, but definitely not one that asked for support.

Comment: I still feel like it falls very neatly into place according to your description... not like my perspective might be just a little skewed due to recent frustrations, lol...