# Someone is retagging a bunch of old embarcadero questions

Tags: discussion, tags, old-questions

I just noticed a large number of old C++Builder questions at the top of my list, and on investigating, a user has been going through and deleting the [embarcadero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embarcadero) tag from all the questions. (Embarcadero is the company that publishes C++Builder, and they also publish other related development tools that may be of interest to C++Builder users).

However the person did not delete "borland" tags (the company that was bought out by Embarcadero before Stack Exchange was conceived).

I also could not find any discussion of this tag on "meta". Has this person just taken it on himself to remove this tag for unknown reasons? Or is there discussion about it somewhere that I am overlooking?

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819309/errors-compiling-hello-world-in-c-rad-studio-2010)

Comment: [off-topic] Given the answer in the example question, I've just voted to close it as *simple typographical error*...

Comment: @brasofilo yeah I considered that, but I checked meta for policies about old, bad questions and opinion seemed divided on whether or not it was better to just let sleeping dogs lie.

Comment: Well, that's quite true and the same thought came to me *after* casting the vote... [sight]

Comment: Upvoted. Delphi has been around for like 20 years now, and IMHO many topics are still valid (VCL, WinAPI wrappers, etc) so it is not like we are bringing the outdated/deprecated/abandoneware to surface. They all still popup in search results and everything.

Comment: We have to separate embarcadero and borland. They are two different products.

Comment: Strictly speaking Embarcadero and Borland are not products, or am I missing something?

Comment: @KromStern: They are not, but we can't just eliminate the tags. We have to modify to reflect the actual IDE or compiler. It will take some work.

Comment: @staticx, no borland and embarcadero are not different when it comes to the questions. A question that applies to Borland Delphi3 can be equally valid for codegear delphi 2006 and Embarcadero Delphi XE5. So those tags are often interchangable and always useless.

Comment: @Johan: that's not true. Ever used BorlandC++ Builder 5? There is code in 5 that won't build in 6. It all depends on the context.

Comment: Even if a tag in an question is incorrect/invalid for some reason, I object to folks changing it for the sake of change.  All this does is raise the question to the top of the queue, often suckering folks (before they realize it) into adding comments/answers to years-old queries.  Pointless churn and unnecessary distraction.  (Obviously if the tag is egregiously wrong it should be fixed, but one wonders what could be so egregious after years of going unnoticed.)

Comment: Related discussion: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254250/lets-remove-the-jetbrains-tag

Comment: @staticx: But the fact that "Borland" was the owner of the brand at the time makes no difference. The fact that it's C++ Builder 5 vs. C++ Builder 6 (meaning that they're different versions) does, but EMBT/Borland/CodeGear make no difference. We don't need a separate `Microsoft` tag for every question tagged `winapi`, and there's no need for a separate tag needed for the owner of the C++ Builder or Delphi names either.

Comment: @KenWhite: You are right. I have since reconsidered my stance after thinking about it more.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I have been removing `Embarcadero` tags according to this question at Meta: [Is adding company name tags spam/vandalism?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253840/is-adding-company-name-tags-spam-vandalism) and this post https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/ Embarcadero tagwiki itself was also marked as deprecated.

Embarcadero is clearly a meta-tag that carries no value in itself (see links above).

Seeing negative response from Matt and Berak ([OpenCV 2.3 in Embarcadero C++ Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587319/opencv-2-3-in-embarcadero-c-builder) [OpenCV and RAD studio C++ (getting started)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894106/opencv-and-rad-studio-c-getting-started?noredirect=1#comment36373954_13894106)) I've stopped the edits and not planning to act further until this issue is resolved (or I'm pointed at a way of deleting tags without editing the question).

Comment: I think it carries some value: questions about other embarcadero products are useful to keep an eye on, because there is a lot of overlap. For example a C++Builder dev can learn from questions from Delphi users about VCL components.

Comment: For that example we have `VCL` tag. With almost the same effect we can tag every question with `PC` and `Microsoft` tags, in case someone finds it interesting to keep an eye on.

Comment: VCL was just an example, there are many other common features . I'm not sure if the Microsoft comparison is appropriate , as MS makes a much wider range of products (e.g. operating systems, keyboards), whereas Embarcadero makes software development tools. At any rate, I'm just registering my "vote" that I find the tag useful.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I was not nitpicking. If the only common ground for different areas questions is a company name that made the tools, then this is hardly a valid SO tag. It would be a better fit for CompanyManagementSE or Careers2.0. SO is dedicated to concrete programming problems, and from my understanding there are no such problems that are connected with a company. Problems are connected with tools, frameworks, APIs, etc.

Comment: Seems like a fairly valid cause (especially since it looks like you've killed the tag entirely), though removing borland too would have been a good move.

Comment: Yeah, if `embarcadero` is to be deleted then I don't see any reason why `borland` should not be deleted; they're both companies with similar scope.  The tag `borland-c++` exists in order to refer to that compiler. There's no specific tag to refer to the compiler that is packaged with C++Builder (which is an IDE), I guess somebody could create the `embarcadero-c++` tag in that case . The compiler can be operated independently of the IDE (similar to NetBeans and g++ for example).

Comment: @MattMcNabb then shall we start?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: We have to be careful because there are stark differences between Borland C++ Builder 1-6 and after Embarcadero took over. Also, we also can't make borland-c++ synonymous with all of the IDEs because they are different. I know this because I worked with Borland C++ Builder 5 and 6 for 8 years. Also, I would not tag a Borland C++ question with Delphi. In the UI, there are some similarities but the code to interact with VCL is in C++

Comment: Seems like it needs to be handled on a case-by-case basis. Many tools are referred to colloquially by their company name rather than their "tool" name. Additionally, many companies have their flagship tool as their name (or vice versa). (Eclipse comes to mind; that's not the only tool the Eclipse Foundation builds, though.) The argument here is that the company name matters when that's the term people would be searching on. A borland tag without embarcadero would seem to be missing a critical piece of information and would just lead to follow-ups about what version, etc. Wouldn't it?

Comment: @staticx: There are stark differences between Delphi-7 and Delphi-XE5 as well, yet product name and framework tags work well. Is there a way of differentiating between C++Builder versions other than company owner title perhaps?

Comment: @KromStern: I thought there used to be tags like [borland-c++-5], [borland-c++-6]. I believe that would suffice. Granted, these questions should be minimal. [borland-c++-5] is from Windows 95 days, but it will run on Windows 7 and there are some applications out there that never migrated and still do active development on [borland-c++-5] because it's too expensive to migrate and it still works.

Comment: It's best to post a burnination request for a specific tag before starting with the removal, even if there is a generic discussion which presumably gives you permission.

Answer (score 7):

I've retagged a bunch of old questions.
The problem with the Borland/CodeGear/Embarcadero tag is that they have no discriminating power.

Case in point: [Image output in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418219/image-output-in-c)

The question was originally tagged `[c]` `[borland]`.

Does the question pertain to: Turbo-C? [Turbo-C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C++)? [C++Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++Builder)? Which version? The `borland` tag does not help.

Other questions have tags like:

`[borland]` `[builder]` `[c]`.

Because all of C++Builder uses the same building blocks, the ground work put in place in the very first C++Builder and its [VCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Component_Library) is still very much relevant. Anyway, it turns out that the question is about Embarcadero's [C++Builder XE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++Builder#Embarcadero_C.2B.2BBuilder) and very specific to that version. In order to bring those specifics to the fore I've retagged that to `[c++]`   `[c++builder]` `[c++builder-xe]`. Now it's clear it relates to the `XE` version. This is something that the brand tag does not convey.

Just like it is pointless to tag MySQL questions with `mysql-inc` or `oracle` tags. Or programming questions with `Microsoft`. Or OS X questions with `Apple`.

There is no descriminating power in these company specific tags; in fact they are a clear indicator that the question is mis-tagged and needs review.

I use Embarcadero's products on a daily basis and love their work and their products.

There is a burninate discussion out there here on this very meta site.

Comment: Just for convenience, here's the link to burninate request topic: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254992/tag-cleanup-request-borland