# The [embarcadero] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

There is the useless [embarcadero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embarcadero) tag - a company name that keeps resurrecting in various questions.

It never had gone through the burnination process (at least I could not find it), but according to [someone retagging a bunch of old Embarcadero questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254977/someone-is-retagging-a-bunch-of-old-embarcadero-questions), it has been removed from a bunch of questions in the past.

Since it keeps resurrecting I am accompanying this burninate request with a blacklist request.

---

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?
>   and is it unambiguous?

No. Embarcadero is a company name.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

No. It is not a concept.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No. There are specific tags related to specific Embarcadero products that should be used, like [delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi) and [c++builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2bbuilder). Adding [embarcadero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embarcadero) to the question does not add anything relevant. On the contrary, using that tag alone makes a question not specific enough.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No. It is a company name, not a programming concept, and it does not describe a single product.

Comment: I don't know if blacklisting is appropriate. That thread notes it hasn't been fully burninated (the retagger stopped). However, judging by the absence of old questions, someone has apparently removed it fully after that, but without the formal process. Perhaps we should just burninate once before blacklisting.

Comment: It’s a small number of posts. Just remove the tag and it’ll be gone again. Blacklisting is for tags that keep requiring large burnination efforts.

Comment: The tag is now gone, with a comment left for the user that recreated it to ask them not to do this again.

Comment: Are you sure there's no need to separate Embarcadero and Borland questions somehow though? Delphi could mean any version from 1995 to 2018. I could imagine how these tags once popped up. Creating a tag for every version (as done for Visual Studio) isn't sane, imo.

Comment: Someone or someones are obviously using it to promote the company. I would support both burning and blacklisting with possible revival if it becomes more than a company name. Main reason - does not add anything to the question and most likely never will.

Comment: @DanteTheSmith: noone is doing anything obviously here. The person that re-created the tag has no connections whatsoever with the company, sometimes community members just try to help with tagging. Can we keep the pitchforks in the shed here please?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am thinking of other valid reasons this would come up multiple times and I am hitting a blank. Have you some ideas? What would be a downside if we burn and blacklist? The possibility that something valid gets the same name over time? Or the inconsistency where we don't do the same for other companies?

Comment: @DanteTheSmith: you are assuming the community is one mind and everyone knows what tags have been removed before. Sometimes someone less experienced thinks something is a good idea for a tag, it happens, it is not a big deal. It *doesn't need blacklisting*, just because it cropped up once since the last burnination. It was caught within a month and handled manually, there is no need to go to the drastic step of blacklisting.

Comment: @Lundin there is a world of difference between each Delphi and C++ Builder versions regardless of the company behind - in frameworks, compilers... there are separate tags for each version because many times knowing the version is crucial information. It is common that you add general Delphi tag and then version specific one.

Comment: @DanteTheSmith The blatantly obvious reason is that the company changed name and Borland C++ Builder is something else entirely compared with Embarcadero C++ Builder. And there's a yet another tag called Borland-C++ meaning dinosaur MS DOS compiler.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Yes, my point is rather that the tag system is too blunt for version information. You can include information in the post without using tags for it.

Comment: @Lundin "Are you sure there's no need to separate Embarcadero and Borland questions somehow though?" Point is that Embarcadero's vesrions are so different that separating them from Borland's would mean absolutely nothing. Same goes for Borland.

Comment: @Lundin Tag versioning is all we have right now. You cannot so accurately search info within the question and version where some feature is introduced is usually the one that has most questions and answers about issues. Adding tag with version enables you to search and actually find information fast.