# Merge [jetbrains-rider] into [rider]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

The [jetbrains-rider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetbrains-rider) tag currently has 45 questions, with the oldest one created just over 9 months ago. It's essentially the same tag as [rider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rider) whose excerpt says:

> Rider is a cross-platform (Windows, Linux & macOS) IDE created by JetBrains for the .NET/Mono family of languages such as C#. Use this tag if your questions are specific to using Rider or are specific to Rider's behavior. Rider troubleshooting and bugs are off-topic.

Most questions that have the former are also tagged with the latter. I believe they should be merged.

Answer (score 12):

I concur, this seems pretty clearly reasonable, with one small change:

The resulting tag should be [jetbrains-rider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetbrains-rider), with the current tag wiki from [rider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rider), and a synonym created from [rider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rider) to [jetbrains-rider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetbrains-rider).

I'll do this in a week or so if no one raises any objections.

Comment: Personally, I'd be in favour of [rider-ide] (inline with [\[*-ide\]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B*-ide%5D&searchOn=1) and [intellij-idea]) instead of [jetbrains-rider]. Though I agree the more specific parent tag is a better choice.

Comment: My only objection to this is consistency. All of `[resharper]`, `[dottrace]`, `[dotmemory]`, `[dotpeek]`, and `[dotcover]` don't have a `jetbrains-` prefix. I guess the question comes down to whether or not "rider" can be reasonably mistaken for something else.

Comment: @41686d6564 That's a reasonable objection.  I *think* I prefer the prefix (or some other sort of disambiguation) here because "rider" is a common English word, whereas the rest are not.  But I'm open to arguments that I'm wrong and it's clearly understandable.

Comment: I agree with [jetbrains-rider]/[rider-ide]. If we leave [rider] I am sure some misconceptions will appear in the future. Some other tags have shown this behaviour before because of them being a common english word. The ONLY problem I see with [*-ide] is that initials tend to be somewhat problematic for non native speakers as they change from language to language but this is maybe a trifle.

Answer (score -2):

I have some experience with JetBrains products. Using the `ide` suffix (e.g. `rider-ide`) could give overall tag consistency to SO and be an important step towards eventually burninating the behemoth [ide tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ide) by gradually adding synonyms.

It also saves keystrokes and would allow to list all IDEs in the tag search page with just 3 keystrokes... Might be the perfect solution.

Using a prefix `JetBrains` seems like a worst choice because you'll need more keystrokes before getting to the IDE specific tag you actually want.

Comment: I do _not_ really have enough experience with those tags but I would expect questions tagged [jetbrains-ide] (this tag already exists) to be about a different topic compared to questions tagged [rider] or [resharper]. No? In other words, it's similar to how the [visual-studio] tag is different from [c#] or [.net].

Comment: "Using a prefix JetBrains seems like a worst choice because you'll need more keystrokes before getting to the IDE specific tag you actually want" if I write rider on the tag picker I find [rider], [crossrider] and [jetbrains-rider] ordered by number of questions.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine this is well explained [in this thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254250) also linked from the tag wiki. A parallel comparison would be for example [Papyrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papyrus_(software)) which is mostly based on Eclipse and thus shares a lot of features (there are several IDEs like this). In my experience users searching for one IDE won't be looking into meta-tags like JetBrains-IDE and prefer to have all their search results under a single tag (this comes with some IDE specific duplication but even tiny features tend to be specific).

Comment: @Braiam writing JetBrains you get 8 tags now, and if all the Jetbrains products were retaged that would become [thirty](https://www.jetbrains.com/products/). When writing/editing a Q you only get 6 tags in the preview. But even overlooking that, using a suffix would solve the problem of listing all IDEs effectively in [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags). While using a prefix would only group 1 vendor. Also, there's a natural tendency to start typing the tag as it's written so putting in a prefix would tend to be cumbersome for less experienced (perhaps the majority of ) users.

Comment: @Braiam using a prefix is still the overall worst option.

Comment: Leaving [rider] as is, is the worst option. Anything that isn't plain [rider] is better.