# Isn't teltonika tag (a company) advertising too much for it?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I came over a post tagged [teltonika](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/teltonika)

This tag has this description:

*Teltonika is a company which provides different devices to Overcome the challenges of IoT (Internet of Things) and achieve its full potential with GPS trackers,Teltonika M2M, fleet management, industrial routers etc.*

Isn't this tag description advertising too much for that company?

Comment: Moot since companies don't get tags.

Comment: If you have a suggestion on how to make this description more factual and better fit what a description should be (a description of what the tag is about and how to use it), feel free to suggest it.

Comment: Currently the only use of this tag is to classify products of teltonika company. Routers, GPS, Fleet Manager...: it's large. If I create my Spounz company, may I also create a Spounz tag to speak about Routers, GPS that I will also create, in S.O.? And any other company creating GPS or router may create its tag in S.O.?

Comment: This is what the tag for Oracle says *Oracle Database is a Multi-Model Database Management System created by Oracle Corporation. Do NOT use this tag for other products owned by Oracle, such as Java and MySQL.* Teltonika should be similar, be specific about the product.

Comment: And I don't know which telonika product this telonika tag should then represent by default. Is there a product of that company that is so well known that it justifies to separate it from others of the same kind? Among routers or gps? Else, I think that this tag has only an advertising goal for that company.

Comment: Unfortunately, an enormous number of tags are IMO way too spammy, both for open-source and commercial products. I think it's because the people who create the tags just copy&paste the product blurb from the product website.

Comment: Very similar to _oracle_ is the _apache_ tag. While not denoting a company, the tag is used for a product (httpd) with the proper usage info in the tag description, but constantly used for all kinds of other products associated with the ASF. This one has been discussed multiple times in the past, but its wrong use is a constant annoyance

Answer (score 26):

It is. I'd argue the entire tag is unneeded. The consensus from my understanding is that company tags are too broad anyway*.

As per [past discussions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253840/14998487) and the tag should be removed as [done before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333833/14998487), where appropriate product/API tags should be added/created instead.

---

*While [oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) technically breaks this it is only used for the database and [it should be renamed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427484/14998487).

Comment: Then also create a synonym, because otherwise the oracle tag is going to be back in 0.00001 seconds flat :)

Comment: I'd be glad to, but a distinct lack of rep is keeping me from doing that. So... Feel free to give me some bounties :)

Comment: @Gimby FYI, I went ahead and made a [rename/synonym request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427484/14998487).

Answer (score -11):

The tag description was created by a regular SO user, someone who doesn't seem to be affiliated with the company (but uses their products), so it doesn't count as spam or advertising. The tag description is marginal, but it's at least better than nothing.

It might be a problem that the tag appears to cover so many different products, or it might not be a problem at all. If the differences between these products is superficial, it would make sense to keep it under one tag, potentially with a rename ([teltonika-devices]?). For example, everything that's exactly what happened with [jetbrains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jetbrains): It was used to describe a [common functionality](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254250/6083675) across several products, so it was simply renamed to better reflect that. If the products are related in name only, it would make sense to break it up into different tags in the same way that the tag for Apple was split into many different tags. Without an expert in Teltonika, it's impossible to decide which is the right choice. A note: full burnination requires the tag to [fail all 4 of the criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/6083675), which it does not:

2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?  Yes. While the tag name and description aren't great, most of the questions are about parsing the response from these various devices using code.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post? Yes, because Teltonika devices (at least the GPS ones) send their data in one of several related formats that are only used by Teltonika (e.g. "Codec 8").

My recommendation is therefore to **leave the tag alone** until an expert can weigh in. It only has 20 questions and shows no signs of getting too many more in the future, so it would be easy enough to retag if needed in the future. Otherwise, there's no easy way to know which questions used to have the tag after it gets removed. If someone is looking for information on (say) their GPS products, then the tag could be useful since over half of the questions are about GPS.

It would make sense to clean up the wiki a little (though like I said, it really needs an expert):

> Use for programming questions about Teltonika's IoT (Internet of Things) devices, such as GPS trackers, routers, modems, etc.

Note: There are questions that [mention the word](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22teltonika%22+is%3Aq) but don't have the tag, so it might make sense to even add it to some questions. Still, that's only 56 questions, which is still manageable.

Comment: One problem: Some additional `navtelecom`, `jimi`, `ruptela`, `sensata`, `suntech` tags can then follow: they are also gps manufacturers. And `sierra`, `peplink`, `advantec` tags, for routers, as they are  concurrents manufacturers of telonika. If you allow telonika gps to be emphasised then others trademarks might have the right to follow. On S.O. a tag must have a purpose, a goal, a clear, perfectly clear utility to justify its existence. Which one has telonika one? None. I see no way telonika product range could be specific among others. No way to justify it to be created.

Comment: `oracle` has its tag because quite every developer unify it with its database. But if you test `ibm` tag, you won't find it. `ibm-cloud`, `ibm-mq`, as/400 or iseries? Yes. And it's fine if a tag is created for a specific model of telonika: if the `tl02458gps` exists and has so special drivers or API that need to be discussed regularly, then a tag is justified for it. But if you don't see the `ibm` tag alone, then `telonika` neither. And telonika tag description explain the problem. What is the goal of that tag? Let's read its description... It depict the company and it's product range. Only.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan Like I said, "If the products are related in name only, it would make sense to break it up into different tags." However, I don't think anyone here has the expertise to make that call. We would need someone who can identify which questions are about fundamentally different products in order to disambiguate it. It's better to leave the tag alone rather than advocating for a change without having all the information needed to make an informed decision. Removing the tag entirely will make it harder to find the questions that are on the same topic.

Comment: There two cases for the 20 questions using `teltonika` tags: either the `telonika` tag can be removed from them, because what they are speaking about apply to any router or gps and isn't specific to a teltonika product. Either a question does target a teltonika product, and then: 1) it's an unique case and a simple text mention in the post is enough, 2) there many questions among the 20 ones about this _specific product model_ of teltonika, and then `teltonkia` tag should be renamed with the name of that product model: `rut240` or `rutX500` (for their routers model, for example).

Comment: @MarcLeBihan The tag is not eligible for burnination according to the [rules we've established](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/6083675) and breaking it down into different products doesn't seem like a helpful option because many of their different products work the same way, or at least similarly.

Comment: We have 20 questions having that tag now, not 1,000. The problem might be treated early. At least the tag name should be suffixed with something asking not to use it anymore, and its description changed to explain why it has been discarded. This happen in some stacks.

Comment: We don't tag by company.

Comment: Is the concept described even on-topic for the site? No, "_Teltonika is a company which ..._" isn't an on-topic concept. If the tag needs to stay at least the tag info should be changed. Maybe even the tag should be renamed to perhaps "teltonika-devices" in case each of the device don't warrant a tag of their own.

Comment: @philipxy That's still not a reason to get rid of the tag entirely. In the past, company tags have usually been replaced with other tags separating them into tags for distinct products (e.g., [apple], [microsoft]). However, in other cases, such tags have been renamed (e.g., [jetbrains](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254254/6083675)) or just left alone ([tag:twitter] was the name of a company and a tag—all while [tag:twitter-bootstrap] has more questions).

Comment: @Laurel rename the tag with a name and/or description asking no to use it anymore. In the stack exchange Music Fan you have tags such as:
`identify-this-genre` with this description: "NO LONGER ON TOPIC. DO NOT USE. IDENTIFICATION QUESTIONS WILL BE CLOSED AS THEY ARE NO LONGER SUPPORTED.". And it's ok. It's a way the tag teltonika can stop being used from now.

Comment: [tag:twitter] is a product: _"Twitter is a microblogging **service**"_