# How to manage tags a companies open source vs 1st party code

Tags: discussion, tags

I work for a company that has a large amount of open source contributions, as well as a growing API community. Should I try to create a new tag for questions about our open source software (such as `companyname-os`) or should I try to organize all questions to the existing generic `companyname` tag.

Comment: Please no! Tags are too many already, rendering them mostly meaningless.

Comment: Recommended read http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Answer (score 4):

[There's prior discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13282/175248) and consensus on this; chiefly, if you want to have tags which represent your company's products (note that I mean *products*, not just stuff branded with your company's *name*; those tags ideally should be removed [per earlier discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338073/1079354)), the community must be actively using them enough to warrant the questions on Stack Overflow.

This comes with some additional advice as well, available [in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support); the entire thing is a must-read but I feel that this part is especially prudent.

> Finally, *monitor the site*. Stack Overflow gets thousands of questions every day and they are often answered within minutes. Be responsive: monitor the tags related to your product, search for questions that might not be tagged correctly and improve them, and review and improve answers.
>
> Remember, Stack Overflow is moderated by the community. If you want your customers to have a good experience on the site, you need to be there to guide them if they aren't familiar with how things work.

If your company doesn't have enough members of Stack Overflow which can help with moderation of the tag, then it would be best to hold off any campaign with Stack Overflow until such a time when you have that.

Answer (score 3):

Don't create tags for companies, these are too broad and don't really tell you what a question is about.

Quoting from [Are company-name tags like [microsoft] and [apple] useful?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190914/167646):

> Things like "Microsoft" and "Apple" are users tagging things
> incorrectly. The company name is meant to be a *part* of the tag, like
> "Microsoft Power Point" would be [microsoft-powerpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-powerpoint), but users
> type it with a space as "microsoft powerpoint" and it suddenly becomes
> two tags [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) and [powerpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerpoint). The brand is part of
> the product name. Though we oftentimes just crop off the brand name
> because it makes the tag longer and it's not really useful.
>
> The [microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/microsoft) and [apple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple) tags are not useful at all.
> Microsoft and Apple both have a zillion different products under them,
> which makes these tags extremely ambiguous at best.
>
> These tags should both be burned to death.

Quoting from [Is adding company name tags spam/vandalism?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253840/247702):

> In general, we prefer product tags to company tags.
>
> Company tags don't tell us anything about the content of the question;
> they are therefore considered meta tags.  The proof: any question that
> would be asked about *a company* on Stack Overflow would most likely
> be off-topic.
>
> **Further Reading**   [The Death of Meta Tags](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags)

Additional reading material:

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging
- [How do I correctly tag my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18878/167646)

Comment: The current situation is that people are tagging their questions about our open source work with `companyname`. I should delete those tags and make sure they include a `product/library/reponame` tag instead?

Comment: @tristansokol Yeah, that would be better. Hopefully there aren't too many questions incorrectly tagget yet :) Also take some time educate your users on correctly tagging, if possible.