# Tag Info of [hashicorp] is no more than About Us page of company. Should this be edited?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I have absolutely no idea about "hashicorp" product. [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hashicorp/info) of [hashicorp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hashicorp) is no more than About Us page of company. There are 53 questions [tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hashicorp?sort=newest) with it.

Should this be edited to explain more about its product (for which the tag is valid) instead of information about the company?

Comment: To make it worse, the text was copied from Wikipedia, which should be rejected straight away... and [the tag also probably need to be cleaned up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253840/is-adding-company-name-tags-spam-vandalism)

Comment: Should we take the tag to the edge (hashi) of a bridge (hashi) and push it over with chopsticks (hashi)?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm good call, we should quickly run (hashiru) and do that.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This tag probably shouldn't exist at all!

Hashicorp is a company. They're responsible for several products which are on-topic here, like [vagrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vagrant), [consul](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/consul), and [terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terraform). However, these products all have their own tags. There's no need to tag the company separately; [company tags are bad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253840/is-adding-company-name-tags-spam-vandalism).

Answer (score 11):

The tag excerpt is intended to explain [when to *use*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/) the tag.  It is not for describing a company or a *product*.  Now of course, it might explain that the tag should be used for questions about a product, but that is clearly not the case for this tag.

So yes, this should be edited to meet guidelines.