# Rename tag [trading-view] to [tradingview-api] request

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Please rename tag [trading-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trading-view) to [tradingview-api]. Because the name of the corresponding company is [TradingView](https://www.tradingview.com) (**without** the space between "Trading" and "View"). It is similar to JavaScript has a tag [javascript] not [java-script].

Looking forward to hearing from you...

Comment: Please start just with the tags rename

Comment: *we'd like to rename them* who is the "we" you're talking about?

Comment: I am a TradingView employee, 'we' == my company. What exactly is wrong with the description text? We'll correct it

Comment: to be complete: the tag pine-script was added [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41941783/2) and I think trading-view was added [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44126200/1)

Comment: If you're affiliated with the group that maintains these technologies, [you need to disclose that explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). Also please remember that we're a *community driven site*. The community (within rules) gets to decide what the proper response to your request is. Most of us who frequent Meta are also generally much more interested in quality, meaning we might choose to prioritize fixing the tag wikis before renaming. You're asking for a favor, which is fine, but be careful that you don't come off as thinking it's an obligation.

Comment: I'm not advertising for my company. The dash in the middle of the tag looks ugly. Take for example JavaScript has a tag javascript, not java-script. Why PineScript has a tag pine-script then? Don't you want to have all tags to have consistent names?

Comment: I've edited the tag descriptions. Please check...

Comment: @sirflipthethird they might want to show edit history which is not really needed as we have the [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/377535/revisions) for that. I edited the post to rectify the issue.

Comment: I think you need a meta question like this for a tag rename, but not to suggest an edit to the tag wiki. On the "questions tagged X" pages you linked, click "Improve tag info."

Comment: OK, I've clicked on "Improve tag info." for the trading-view and pine-script tags. So this request would be related to the trading-view tag rename only. Thanks to @keith-m

Comment: @vitvlkv umm... I've renamed the tag to tradingview-api as that doesn't seem unreasonable... the tag wiki descriptions could still use some work though.

Comment: @vitvlkv The reason the tag was added as `pine-script`, is that all your [wiki pages](https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Category:Pine_Script) refer to the language as `Pine Script` with a space in it. So I suggest you fix that first, so that people would know what to call it, when they come to SO.

Answer (score 1):

We have [a policy against "company tags"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253910/103167), so you need to explain why this tag shouldn't be outright deleted (or changed to a family of tags, each for a single product).

There's no point in changing punctuation on a tag that isn't needed in the first place.

Comment: Likely the latter (make product tags instead of company tags), since it sounds like some people were getting some use out of them? After all, someone ELSE, outside the company, created them. Or is that typical?

Comment: It looks like there are also some Q's where trading-view is the only tag (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53690406/rsi-ping-pong-signals ), so someone should probably look at those and see if other tags apply. Maybe it should be renamed to tradingview-api or something, if nothing else applies. I'm not sure what language this is. Pine Script? Maybe have trading-view alias to the Pine Script tag?

Comment: I'm strongly disagree with you, @BenVoigt, there is a BIG point to use CORRECT names for the people, companies etc.

Comment: How does your policy against 'company tags' relates to such tags like https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter ?
The only reason I've asked you guys to do the rename is just to fix a mistake. You don't like complany tags - OK, rename it to [tradingview-api] or delete the [trading-view] tag. After all, the most of the questions tagged with [trading-view] are about Pine Script.

Comment: @vitvlkv: Those tags reference product names, not companies.  I would have assumed that "TradingView" was also a product name, except your question clearly and unambiguously is arguing about "the name of the corresponding company".  There should be a tag per product.  If you agree with doing `tradingview-api` and `pine-script` instead of a company tag, please edit your question to reflect that.  Finally, policy is not a you-vs-me thing.  We're all members of this site, it is *our* policy (and I am only a member, with no power to implement your tag synonym request).

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TradingView tradingview - it's a service and a social network (the article in Russian, but the very first sentence there says exactly I've written). The company's name is 'TradingView Inc'. Giving the tag name 'TradingView' is just more useful for users who look for it - that's my IMHO.

Comment: OK, I've edited the Q. Now, I'm asking about renaming [trading-view] to [tradingview-api]

Comment: I'm a bit too late to the party here, since I was never notified from the meta, even if I'm following these tags. My concern is regarding the use of `tradingview-api`. AFAIK, the TradingView platform does have it's own API that is **only** available to developers by signing a NDA. So therefore, the `tradingview-api` tag is probably not a good idea. Just keeping it as `tradingview` as it also reflect the public web platform would then be a more natural choice. Especially considering the quantity of 1st time SO users, using that tag, so they probably does not know to use/meaning of `-api` tag.