Synonymize [plotly-python] to [plotly] or remove [r-plotly] synonym
Having plotly-python when we can use pythonplotly together seems redundant, hence, it should be synonymized.
There used to be a r-plotly which is now a synonym of plotly. It is only logical to do the same for plotly-python as well. There is a meta post that asks for r-plotly synonym to be revoked; while I don't think having to search for two tags instead of one is an inconvenience, I agree that we need to be consistent:

... However, the current situation is inconsistent (R tag being a synonym, python tag remaining separate) and should be amended independent of my personal preference.

 Link to the comment above (emphasis mine). 
Right now there are 576 questions tagged with plotly-python but not python. These need to be tagged with python.
So, two questions:

To address this inconsistency, I propose to synonymize python-plotly to plotly. But do you think revoking r-plotly synonym is the better approach?

If you agree with the proposed synonym, are there any other steps (beside retagging those 576 questions) that we should take prior to approving this?



Update:

Please not that plotly.js is not the same as plotly. plotly covers plotly.r, plotly.js, plotly.py, plotly.rs (for Rust), etc. See https://github.com/orgs/plotly/repositories

There are 6000+ questions tagged with python plotly but not plotly-python.

When there was an r-plotly tag, there were so many questions that had r plotly but not r-plotly. Simply having a specific tag for each of these does not seem feasible nor helpful.


Although I am advocating for synonymizing, I am open to the other option. But the status quo is not acceptable (having one as a synonym and not the other).

"Having plotly-python when we can use python plotly together is redundant, hence, it should be synonymized." - Synonymizing is by no way the only tool for remove a redundancy. The most direct tool is burninating an extra tag. And it looks for me as a proper solution As for "consistent synonimizing", it seems to be controversial at least: If r-plotty is a synonym for a plotty, and plotty-python will be synonim of a plotty, then plotty-python and r-plotty will mean the same. Looks weird.

@Tsyvarev although I don't think it's weird, I see your point. So, what do you suggest? revoking r-plotly as synonym?

Yes, I don't find correct to have r-plotty to be a synonym of plotty. The first one is about r language, and the second one is not about r at all. How they could be synonyms?

@Tsyvarev I think what you are suggesting would be a much bigger haul. First, plotly is about r, python, matlab; plotly.js is not. Second, if we want to go in that direction, then a lot of things need to be retagged. Simply synonymizing plotly-python with plotly, give us the desired result: Don't use language specific library tags, instead tag the library and the language separately. See RyanM's comment on the other post.

" I think what you are suggesting would be a much bigger haul. First, plotly is about r, python, matlab; plotly.js is not" - but according to plotly.py's readme, "Built on top of plotly.js, plotly.py is a high-level, declarative charting library". Same with plotly for R, and I don't feel like looking up matlab, but I have a feeling it'll say the same thing

@Zoe "plotly" is different from "plotly.js" in my mind. And if you look at the questions and how they're tagged, you'll see that majority of users use the tag as how I am describing it. If read what you quoted from my last comment: "plotly is about r, python, matlab; plotly.js is not". That's the distinction I am making.

"plotly is about r, python, matlab" - I don't understand how a library could be about several languages at once. It could be a language-agnostic concept, which has "ports" to many languages. Like YAML.

@Tsyvarev plotly is an organization responsible for maintaining many repositories namely plotly.py, plotly.r, plotly.rs ....

"plotly is an organization ..." - On Stack Overflow we do not create tags which denotes organization: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253840/is-adding-company-name-tags-spam-vandalism/. If you want to change description of plotty tag from plotty.js library to organization which maintains that library, then I am strongly in opposition to that.

@Tsyvarev that is totally twisting my words. Of course I do not want to do that. All I am saying, is that plotly is the umbrella under which we have packages for many languages. Yes, they are based on (APIs) plotly.js. Moreover, I am saying that [tag:plotly] is not exclusively used for JS, but rather any question that uses a flavor of that package. I'll go back to my first question from you:  what do you suggest we do here? As I said, the status quo is not acceptable. I have already laid out two options. Let's be a bit more effective and discuss which one is better or propose another way!

Before suggesting anything about the tags, I prefer to firstly understand meaning of those tags, especially of the plotty one. Current description of that tag is "charting library for JavaScript". If meaning of the tag remains, then the tag is about JS, and neither r-plotty nor python-plotty should be synonym for it. If the tag means organization or "umbrella", then the tag should be destroyed. If the tag means technology for plotting charts, and that technology has single, well-known port to python, then python-plotty could be removed in favor of python + plotty.

As far as I can tell, it's already synonymized, although something might be broken. When I check the [tag:plotly-python] tag, almost all the results are tagged [tag:plotly], and several are not actually tagged [tag:plotly-python]. What's going on?

Despite the fact that supposedly "Plotly is an open source, high-level, declarative charting library for JavaScript", only a tiny fraction of questions in the tag are also tagged as Javascript questions. Among the rest, Python seems to be slightly more popular than R. About 10% or so don't seem to have any Python, R or Javascript language tag - more than the Javascript-tagged ones - but those commonly either tag something like node.js or something like matplotlib. There are finally a few dozen questions about using Plotly from Julia.

@Tsyvarev sorry for the late response. Let me explain why it should be a synonym with an example. Take [tag:tensorflow]; we don't have py-tensorflow or r-tensorflow or cpp-tensorflow. We have one tag and we use it in combination with [tag:python], [tag:r], or [tag:c++], etc. This is not much different if not the same. From the tag excerpt: "TensorFlow is an open-source library and API designed for deep learning, written and maintained by Google. Use this tag with a language-specific tag ([python], [c++], [javascript], [r], etc.)" p.s. we can edit tag wiki for [tag:plotly] if needed.

"we can edit tag wiki for plotly if needed." - This is what your question post should start from. In the current form the tag plotty means specifically JavaScript library, so its appliance for Python questions doesn't look correct. If you want to treat plotty as language-agnostic library, then following retagging has a sense. (But as I already said, synonyms looks weird).

@Tsyvarev it's already edited. I took out "for javascript" part. p.s. if you look at excerpt history, that was my mistake anyway.

In my view, tags of the form [language-technology] are only valuable when they further disambiguate over using [language] [technology] separately. (The [language] should be tagged anyway, so this doesn't cut down on the number of tags; but aside from that, it's not desirable to spam tags on questions, therefore it's not desirable to help people circumvent the already generous limit of 5 tags.)
For example, a question tagged [python] [typing] is expected to be about how Python's type system works, while a question tagged [python] [python-typing] is about the typing standard library module and its support for type annotations. There are only a few valid questions in the former group, but the latter should definitely not be confused with them - nor should they be grouped with questions about the typing discipline of other languages (which will tend to be more theoretical).
In the current case, none of that reasoning seems to apply. There doesn't seem to be anything meaningfully different about using the Plotly library from different languages via their corresponding bindings, and the library isn't a feature of any of them - it's just third-party support.
So it makes perfect sense, to me, to just use [plotly] to tag these questions, regardless of the implementation language. If anything, Python currently has a better claim to this tag than R does, based on pure statistics. (Strangely, even though it's a JavaScript library, it's apparently used far more often from either Python or R than from JavaScript.)

There are some features that really depend on that specific language though. From an R perspective, there's the ggplotly function which I use often, and which recreates a plot created using the ggplot2 package using plotly. Other language bindings don't offer similar functionality (perhaps mainly because ggplot is specific to R, even though there is a python package which replicates most of its functionality).

@ErikA if those specific features are popular, they can have their own tags; and if it's somehow necessary to disambiguate those features by putting the language name in the tag, that can happen too. There's already a ggplotly tag, and tagging a question [r] [plotly] [ggplotly] is IMO perfectly reasonable.
