# Is it acceptable to use Stack Overflow as a Q&A for a specific product?

Tags: support, faq, outsourcing

I work for a small software start-up and I love Stack Overflow. Is it acceptable to encourage our customers to post questions on Stack Overflow so we can answer them there and also let the community benefit from it?

Would customers shy away from the fact that it is too public?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Comment: You've got to remember a well meaning customer could post a question only to have it closed and hence unanswerable.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253394/third-party-development-support-hosted-by-stack-overflow/253584#253584 ; _Would customers shy away from the fact it is too public?_ That's a question for you to answer, we don't know your customers or buisness.

Comment: Related: [Is self-promotional question tagging allowed? If not, how do you handle it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253144/456814).

Answer (score 157, accepted):

I work for Stack Exchange on the community team; I'm putting together some very specific [guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) for our help center regarding this right now. This *can* work out well, but the following needs to be in place:

- There have to be some existing questions about your product on the site, preferably tags specific to your product to accompany them. It's generally best if these come from our community, we advise *against* seeding the site with questions about your product. Our community is *very* sensitive to spam and might see your attempt as such.
- Your developers *must* be active on the site. They need enough rep to edit, re-tag, close, re-open, etc. They won't be able to be of much help to your customers if they don't have at least editing privileges. Preferably, they've got more to their credit on the site than *just* questions about your product.
- Your developers *must* monitor your tags, and jump in to answer questions. It's fine if the rest of the community does this, but a big mistake is thinking that if people just ask on Stack Overflow, *someone* will probably answer them. It's your responsibility to see that your customers have a pleasant experience on our community moderated site.

There's more to it, the content on your site that instructs people to come to Stack Overflow matters quite a bit. Folks need to know where to go based on what they want to do (and understand that they can't accomplish everything at Stack Overflow). You should have some kind of developer 'connection' page where you:

- Point bug reports and feature requests at bug trackers that you maintain (not for the site)
- Instruct people on what tags to use, and remind them to also apply the appropriate language tags, as needed.
- Make sure their question [is on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and not something [we'd prefer folks not ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
- Make it clear that Stack Overflow is a community run Q&A site for programmers, and not a part of your organization. It's important to set people's expectations correctly when you send them over to us.

You can reach out to us (the community team) via our [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) if you have any additional questions, or would like one of us to look at the content on your site that points people to Stack Overflow. We generally shy away from helping you to create tags - in most cases if a tag doesn't exist for your product, it's probably not yet time to start sending people in our direction.

However, when done correctly, the results can be positively brilliant. Folks might be reluctant to post certain kinds of questions (or questions at all), possibly due to:

- They find the site intimidating, by what they see or what they might have heard
- They don't feel comfortable posting their code (something we pretty much require) in order to get help for something they're paying for
- They're working under some kind of NDA or other agreement which prohibits using public facing sites

.. which leads me to my last point. ***Make sure we're not your only support option*** - and let folks pick which one works the best for them. Make sure they can easily find a place to just ask *you* their question on the same page that points them to us.

That's a lot of oddly-specific guidance, but it's very important to follow it closely - your customers are going to be associating their experience on a community moderated site with *your* product, so you have to make certain you have folks around that can make sure that experience is good.