# Do any companies have agreements with Stack Overflow to use the site as a support channel? What's the best course of action if not?

Tags: discussion, questions, outsourcing

I recently read [Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) and it kind of shocked me because I've seen companies list Stack Overflow as a seemingly legitimate support channel for their services, and I've always just assumed that some kind of deal had been arranged.

Is that kind of arrangement ever the case?  If not, what's the recommended course of action when dealing with a company who claims to use Stack Overflow as their support channel?  If it so happens that the company does indeed have staff who monitor their "tag" here, how would you go about getting your question answered without disrupting Stack Overflow policies if your question isn't necessarily related to coding?

Just in case you haven't seen a case of a company advocating Stack Overflow as a support channel, here's what is currently posted at the top of [OpenShift's Forum](https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift):

[image]

Comment: I'm less offended by this since the link actually leads to a page that states, "You should search before asking."

Comment: @Makoto, I think it's the first time I see a company linking to the page [ask]. Nice touch on their part.

Comment: It's nicer way of writing "get lost".

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> how would you go about getting your question answered without disrupting SO policies if your question isn't necessarily related to coding

Then you don't ask it on Stack Overflow. On Stack Overflow, the rules/scope of Stack Overflow are what counts. It's as simple as that. No matter if a company were to claim otherwise.

However, if a company links to SO for support, there is no immediate need for action, unless they explicitly inform users they should post content that would be out of the scope of the site (bug reports and the like for example). See also [Tim Post's answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product/253852#253852) to the question "[Is it acceptable to use Stack Overflow as a Q&A for a specific product?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product)".

If you notice however that a significant amount of off-topic content is being posted, possibly as a result of such a link, bring it up on Meta and then perhaps someone could contact the company and inform them of the site's purpose and ask them to address any issues we've noticed.

If you feel comfortable doing so, you could even politely point the company at [the link you've posted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) (if there is an easy way to contact them), and advise them to have a look.

Answer (score 22):

Quoting "Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]", note:

> **But I was referred here by [company] for support!**
>
> Yes. For your on-topic, programming-related questions. For your questions having specifically to do with writing code for their API. For questions that involve customer service issues, you need to contact the company directly.

- Asking about *coding* using the API, or about code in the API itself forms perfectly legitimate questions.
- Asking about things that relate to the API but don't have to do with coding (for example, how do I get in contact with the support team) is off topic.

For what it's worth, I'd like to see the OpenShift forums clarify that, and I think Robert did a good job in his answer explaining why.