# Is Stack Overflow suitable as "user forum" for product support?

Tags: discussion, product-support

I was looking at a question installing [WSO2 Governance Registry on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23982417/146325).  Basically it's just a long Java Exception stack.

Normally I would have voted to close this, as Off Topic.  But I like to point the OP to a more pertinent forum for applications (such as Oracle TechNet).  So I googled and was surprised to discover that [the official WS02 support page](https://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance460/Getting+Support) explicitly directs people to "Ask questions in the user forums at http://stackoverflow.com".

On the one hand, I'm sure we're all stoked that Stack Overflow is so respected by companies.  On the other hand [WS02 is a commercial enterprise](http://wso2.com/), so should they be offloading their community support to SO?  Almost [all of the questions tagged WS02](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wso2) remain unanswered, so they seem to be in breach of the conditions stipulated by [Tim Post in this similar thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253852/146325).

Comment: 50% unanswered = almost all?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3966/is-it-okay-to-use-stack-overflow-as-the-support-forum-for-a-product-or-project and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195558/product-support-redirects-to-stack-overflow

Comment: What do you want to know that isn't already covered by http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253849?

Comment: @animuson - fair point. I looked at the recent questions, and exaggerated rather than extrapolated.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - what I wanted to know was whether SO was cool with this specific behaviour.  Your answer says Yes, we're cool.

Comment: We're cool with it, provided people aren't creating a lot of noise with questions we can't answer, like "When will my app get approved?"  See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746

Comment: It does seem a little rude to direct users to ask a question without asking to first search for an existing solution, or mentioning that there are proper SOtiquette rules for asking one. *"We don't want all the hassle of maintaining a helpdesk, so just dump all the clutter over there, will you?"*

Comment: One exceptional case: [Ask Ubunutu](http://askubuntu.com) is a StackExchange site that is explicitly for help with Ubuntu.

Comment: [I've asked about this specific tag before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181147/the-wso2-tag-is-descending-into-anarchy). Shog talked to WSO2 and they did change how they sent people to SO. Not sure that it's got much better though...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The central issue with offloading of customer support questions to StackOverflow is that **the Stack Overflow community gets to decide [whether each question is on topic or not.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**

WS02 seems to have some fundamental misunderstandings about the way Stack Overflow works.  They direct people to the "user forums" on Stack Overflow, even though no such thing exists, and use terms like "keywords" instead of "tags."

That said, there are at least three employees from WS02 that are in [the top contributor list for the WS02 tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wso2/topusers), and their accounts are all in good standing.