# Is creating an account solely to ask and self-answer questions about your own service considered spam?

Tags: discussion, spam

[This account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4102641/exact-online-api-support) appears to exist solely for the purpose of promoting a service by self-answering questions about it.

The account name indicates it is closely linked to the product. Every question asked is about the product. Every answer given is an answer to one of those questions.

Should this be considered spam?

Comment: It appears they are trying to use SO for support of their product.

Comment: Weird account..

Comment: Looks more like they are using SO as their FAQ @bluefeet

Comment: Nuke 'em. Their questions are 'too localized' (an Old Reason but very appropriate here) and/or 'unclear', such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27771024/exact-online-how-can-i-validate-the-data-for-a-rest-api-request), and are bad even while self-answered.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27771024/464709) is only tangentially related to their product, if at all (it's actually about how to validate XML or JSON). We could do very well without it. Coming soon: "Exact Online: how to add two numbers".

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: *actually* it is about how to do this *with their product*, and I seriously doubt if they are interested in answers that do not use it.

Comment: @Jongware, I beg to differ: *You can validate each data format using online tools, jsonlint.com (for JSON) and www.xmlvalidation.com (for XML)* has nothing to do with their product, and the two first paragraphs are only boilerplate about JSON and XML. Only their last paragraph mentions their product, to say it will reply with an error if the request is ill-formed (well, duh).

Comment: Looks like all of the account's [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4102641/exact-online-api-support?tab=questions) have been deleted.

Comment: Well, according to the flag description for spam, it's only spam if they don't disclose their affiliation with the problem. Not to say that the questions don't have other problems, but it's not technically closeable as spam.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It looks like they are attempting to create a support platform on Stack Overflow for their product but happened to go about it the wrong way. While doing this is acceptable, [there are a few guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product) which they obviously didn't follow.

As [Tim Post states](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253852/426671):

> There has to be some existing questions about your product on the site, preferably tags specific to your product to accompany them. It's generally best if these come from our community, we advise against seeding the site with questions about your product. Our community is very sensitive to spam and might see your attempt as such.
>
> Your developers must be active on the site. They need enough rep to edit, re-tag, close, re-open, etc. They won't be able to be of much help to your customers if they don't have at least editing privileges. Preferably, they've got more to their credit on the site than just questions about your product.

At this point, this product/company doesn't appear to have any presence on Stack Overflow.  For the time being, the questions have been removed and they've been directed to several posts about self-promotion and using SO as their support platform.

In the future, if you see something like this, you can use a custom "Other" flag on one of the posts and ask for a moderator to investigate.

Comment: Oh, dear.  Question block; problum solved.

Answer (score 34):

The account's questions tend to be *very* vague and assume knowledge of the product.  Here's an example:

> I want to apply a filter to my request. How can I apply a filter to a REST API request?

[Their self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27776883/exact-online-how-can-i-filter-my-request-in-rest/27776920#27776920), on the other hand, begins like this:

> To retrieve an account ID from an Exact Online division,...

It's not clear to me that these questions and answers are even related to each other, even if we ignore the vagueness and assume both are about the same product.

I would characterize these questions and answers as unhelpful.  I'm not entirely sure I'd call this spam, but it isn't making the site any better.

Comment: I think this gets to the core of the issue.  It doesn't really matter who the user is or what their motives happen to be.  What matters is whether or not their questions/answers are useful/add value to the site.  If they are, then there's no reason to cast them out as spammers just because their useful answers _also_ happen to promote their own product.  And if they aren't, then deal with them the same way any other unhelpful questions/answers are dealt with.

Answer (score 9):

In general, not a problem. This is especially the case when the questions are from real consumers about a reasonably common programming environment, and the company account is just reposting them (after cleaning them up, merging duplicates, et).

In this particular case, none of that appears to have happened. I still wouldn't consider it spam, because I'm not convinced the intent here was necessarily bad. It's just failing for a host of other reasons.

Comment: "With the best intentions" ... reminds me of Steve Rhoades liberating poor Bosco the sea turtle by throwing him into fresh water...