# Is it ok to post a self-answered question about a product I own?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, self-answer, self-promotion

My team recently released a product that has a public api. We provided several api clients, but we want to encourage users to write their own as well.

It is against SO community guidelines to ask a specific question about implementing an api for my product with my own answer?

It would certainly be helpful to anyone looking to consume the api, but I can't deny that I'm also looking to draw new users to use my product.

According to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281771/is-creating-an-account-solely-to-ask-and-self-answer-questions-about-your-own-se), many would say this is NOT ok. However, I'm clearly active on SO for much more than self promotion.

**Update**

I still believe this is not a duplicate because I plan on asking good, specific (but not too specific questions) like a good stack overflow user. However, what is starting to make sense to me from everyone's answer and comments, is that I should either wait for my users to post questions, or wait until I've been asked the same question multiple times and self-answer it. We have good documentation, and it's getting better, but some people just google stack overflow.

Comment: just be careful to ensure it doesn't fit any of the close reasons. to me it sounds borderline too broad

Comment: @KevinB borderline?  Sounds pretty far past the border to me.

Comment: I would agree my example question is far too broad. Perhaps something more like "How do I post a message to the `api/Log` service with javascript?" would be better.

Comment: Specific use cases scoped within the bandwidth of a question/answer and you might be OK.  I'd stay away from some languages, tho (c++, PHP)

Comment: I don't see "How do i do X" as being "Too Broad" unless "X" can be a complete application or module on it's own. hence why i said borderline. In this case, it seems like mentioning the product at all would be unnecessary for a question like this, making it a bad fit for what the op is trying to do.

Comment: @Will Just curious, what was the reason for avoiding certain languages like c++ and php?

Comment: Yes, I know my original example question was too broad. But that wasn't the point of my inquiry.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want to do is write documentation. SO is great, but to some extent having to look here means the API developer has already failed.

Comment: The nominated duplicate IMHO fails to address this question; it is specifically about somebody posting multiple near-duplicates.

Comment: @dan because they are bitter and angry and will downvote anything because their hearts have turned into black lumps of coal due to the horrible languages they code in every day.  And they coordinate dvs and cvs because of the torrent of trash washing over their tags day in and day out.

Comment: @Will Thats what I thought haha

Comment: Check deduplicator's comment on the answer - writing good question to be self-answered is ridiculously hard (especially if you have semi-decent documentation indexed by search engine). Getting -5 for "not even tried to search" not going to make your "seeding" any better. You may get better  return on your time by cleaning up questions asked by actual users.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> "How do I consume my product's API with language X?" with my own answer?

Such a question would unquestionably be Too Broad.

That said, if you can ask *appropriate* questions, then this is acceptable, but *you need to disclose your affiliation with the product* when posting about it.

Comment: Thank you. This was my understanding, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't off base.

Comment: @BenVoigt already pointed this out (indirectly) above, but from [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product/253852#253852) it states: "There has to be some existing questions about your product on the site, preferably tags specific to your product to accompany them. *It's generally best if these come from our community, we advise against seeding the site with questions about your product.* " (Italics added)

Comment: @jrummell: Wishing you success, but I want to stress that writing a good question is often not easy, writing a good self-answered question is quite hard, and if you write it about your own thing, it's really hard. The recommendation for the latter is letting them be asked here organically...

Comment: @Deduplicator that's a good point.