# Merit of a flag category for "it is a customer-support request"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Along the lines of the excellent meta post "[Why we're not customer support for [your favorite company]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)" and [Tim Post's well-expressed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product/253852#253852) thoughts on companies sending support-requests to Stack Overflow, I believe it would be useful to have a uniform flag-type to apply to company-specific questions.

I imagine the flag would be something like the following:

> **it is a customer support request**.
>
> This question appears to be off-topic because it is a customer support
>   request, not a question about a programming problem.

I believe this would improve clarity for the asker when the off-topic question is closed and make it easier for reviewers to agree on the close-reason.

An example of why I believe we need a flag type: "[Internal service error on LinkedIn using the Share API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100042/internal-service-error-on-linkedin-using-share-api)"

The question is:

- not too broad
- objectively about programming
- and the user has included his/her relevant code

Yet, it *should* be closed because the Stack Overflow community would have to guess why the vendor/company is throwing server-side errors and, as quoted above, we're not customer support for companies.

Should we have a flag category for customer-support requests?

Comment: Oh!  I never considered doing that.  I have loads of them I could send in..

Comment: Practically all SO questions are customer support requests.  But don't always need a company to provide it, typically because they have enough customers that visit here which have dealt with a similar problem or know the product well enough.  Linkedin just isn't that lucky yet.

Comment: @HansPassant My experience hasn't been that most questions on SO are customer support requests.  Even if the end application of a solved question is company-specific, the questions that I generally see not getting closed contain content that could be helpful to others.

Comment: _Practically all SO questions are customer support requests._ The company being mainly MS..

Answer (score 29):

If something is clearly a customer support request that cannot be answered by a standard user on Stack Overflow, feel free to close it using a custom off topic reason.

I don't know that we get enough of these to create yet another close reason just for them.

For the specific example you point out: I have occasionally seen good answers to questions like these here. While the cause of the problem may be something server-side, often average users have created or found workarounds that they can provide as answers. These answers frequently have code explaining how to detect the problem and how to deal with it when this happens.

Things like "iTunes Connect is down and I can't submit my app" are clearly off topic, since there's nothing anyone on Stack Overflow can do about that, but the one you point to might be addressable by developers here.

Comment: I suppose it's true that the "other" approach works, but then everyone has to type/copy-paste/write a plugin.  Moderation should be as easy as possible on a community driven site; flagging posts is fast and easy because it's a few clicks.  I can see your point of view on the community being able to troubleshoot server-side/blackbox problems, but for company-specific questions and general errors, it's not very helpful to others in the future.

Comment: @tristan - The downside to adding another close reason is that it makes closing everything else slightly harder by adding another choice in that dialog. Every choice added there makes the overall closing process harder, so the volume has to be there to support it. I haven't seen support request questions coming in with anywhere near the frequency of things covered by the other close reasons, so I'm fine with it remaining an "other".

Comment: I understand that there's a cost in adding another choice, but  "Another Reason>Off-topic>X" is deep enough down the chain that it's experienced reviewers using those options.