# Why was my flag of this off-topic customer-service question declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, moderation

While looking for information on the software product Glympse, I discovered that they're among the third party vendors who provide a link to a Stack Overflow tag alongside the "official" support channels on their site. Looking through the questions tagged with their tag, I noticed that number of them appear to be low quality and off-topic for SO.

One that specifically jumped out at me was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470082/glympse-api-key-request): it's clearly not an answerable, on-topic Stack Overflow question, as the user is essentially asking if Glympse can expedite their request for an API key. Should be a slam-dunk case for closure, right?

I wasn't sure how exactly to handle these sorts of cases, so I browsed around on Meta looking for information on what to do about questions that should have been submitted to a third party support channel. I found [this Meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/282993/merit-of-a-flag-category-for-it-is-a-customer-support-request) where someone had suggested a specific flag reason for this type of question, and saw that Brad Larson had instructed them thusly:

> If something is clearly a customer support request that cannot be answered by a standard user on Stack Overflow, feel free to close it using a custom off topic reason.

Perfect! I flagged the question with the following flag message:

> This should be removed, as it is not a programming related question but rather a customer service request for Glympse. They're misusing Stack Overflow by linking to it as their "developer forum" on the Glympse developer web site.

However, my flag was declined with the standard message:

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Can a moderator (or anyone else) clarify if and why this flag was inappropriate? I thought I was following pretty clear instructions. I've also got another pending custom flag drawing attention to particularly inappropriate answers posted by Glympse's reps, so I'm curious to see the fate of that flag as well.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Community Managers are already aware that Glympse is not clear as to what Stack Overflow is for, and will reach out to them to help them communicate this to their customers better.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I appreciate you adding that - I wasn't sure if a follow-up discussion should be posted about the broader case of Glympse, but I'm glad to hear someone's already on it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you believe the question is off-topic, then you should vote to close it or flag it for closure. At that time, it will go to the Close Review Queue for the community to review it.

Moderators should be flagged for things the community cannot handle themselves. This is not one of those things so the flag was declined.

Comment: I don't yet have the rep to Vote to Close - is there some other workflow that I don't understand that I should have been going through that would let me "flag it for closure"? Or is this just to say that I should have left this type of off-topic questions alone until I have close-vote privileges?

Comment: @sphanley When you flag the post you should have chosen "should be closed..." rather than "needs moderator attention".  You can't *vote* to close, but you can *flag* for closure.

Comment: @sphanley When you open the flag window you'd select > should be closed, then one of the options presented.  You used "in need of moderator intervention" which wasn't correct in this case. As I said, we should be used when the community can't handle something - closing questions normally isn't one of those things we need to process.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I just misunderstood the advice Brad had given on the old Meta question, since I couldn't identify which of the "should be closed..." flag reasons best addressed the problem with the post.

Answer (score 9):

You flagged the post for moderator attention.  You should have flagged the post for closure instead.