# Allow >3k users to flag for closure if they are out of close votes

Tags: feature-request, flags, vote-to-close

Related: [Can >3k users flag for closure if they are out of close votes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360302/can-3k-users-flag-for-closure-if-they-are-out-of-close-votes)

If a user with 3k or more of rep is out of close votes for the day, but still has flags, they should have the option to flag for closure. Right now, the options for such a user who finds a closeable question are not ideal. They could:

- Downvote only (a single downvote doesn't have a great effect, especially not an immediate one, and someone who has used all of their close votes might also be low on or out of regular votes)
- Flag as Very Low Quality (a [controversial](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357344/6471538) practice, and this flag is only available for some questions)
- Flag for moderator attention (sends the flagger into [that dark place where there are only declined flags and gnashing of teeth](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296059/why-was-my-flag-of-this-off-topic-customer-service-question-declined))
- Do nothing (simply shifts the responsibility of keeping the site clean onto others)
- Ask in chat for others to close flag or close vote (inefficient, and still shifts responsibility onto others)
- Make a note of the question URL and come back the next day (equivalent to procrastination, keeps garbage on the site open longer than it should be)

Since close flags work slightly differently to close votes, a >3k user who is out of close votes should be warned or asked for confirmation before the system will let them cast a regular close flag, such as:

> You are out of close votes for the day. Would you like to cast a regular close flag? Warning: Close flags are subject to being *Declined* and too many declined flags can result in a flag ban.

Comment: Weren't there some average numbers floating around at how many people *actually* run into the flag cap?  I don't recall it being a very high number or percentage of active flaggers, either.  That is to say...you're not likely to run into the issue of running *out* of close votes that often.

Comment: @Makoto I get 50 close votes a day, and 100 flags. I can *easily* burn through all those close votes just hanging out on the new questions page for an hour or two. I *rarely* get anywhere close to the flag cap, and it seems a shame that all those flags are wasted.

Comment: The close-vote queue is at >9k for years now. For everything you flag into the queue, you'll have to do ~5 times the amout of reviews there, otherwise it's just adding to the pile which is never touched. The problem is that there is more crap to close than people willing to use their close-votes. But flagging in addition won't solve the problem.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what chat rooms you're posting in, but if it's bad enough that its closure *cannot* wait a day, then SOCVR will probably be willing to jump on it fairly quickly. ([Read this first](https://socvr.org/faq))

Additionally, from my editing experience as pre-2K, the best way to handle posts if you find yourself *frequently* hitting ratelimits is to use your Favorites list to make a hit list. It's kind of equivalent to noting the URL down and waiting for the next day, but it's much more convenient.

Remember: closure is never *urgent* save for blatant trash. A 5 year old post that's only now closable (closible? closeable?) due to a more recent change in the rules can sit for another day with barely any views. For a help vampire that keeps coming back, downvotes will contribute to question bans too.

Comment: *closureable* has a nice ring to it