# Can (should) we preemptively create a tag with no questions asked?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-process

The [official Windows 10 Developer Program site](http://dev.windows.com/en-us/featured/Windows-Developer-Program-for-IoT) has a link on its front-page to a [Stack Overflow tag that doesn't exist yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wdpforiot).  Presumably they want us to start using that tag.  I was going to create the tag and a wiki page for it, but I couldn't figure out how without asking a question first.

Is there a way to do this?  **Should** we even do this?

<sub>Honestly I don't think it's a great tag-name, but it's linked by the Windows 10 site, so...</sub>

Comment: Also, ew:  they condensed "Windows Developer Program for IoT" into [wdpforiot]?  That looks like pure gibberish, who's going to find that tag even if they have a relevant question?  UPDATE:  I even had to edit that comment, because I typed the tag wrong.  Pure gibberish.

Comment: And shame on them for not relating *anything* about our standards. Stop directing crap traffic our way!

Comment: Well, there is no way to create a tag without any questions for it. But in this case, that seems a good thing, as it does not seem a good tag for on-topic questions.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but assuming there was a tag made with no questions, wouldn't the Roomba just come along and eat it?

Comment: The tags created for this should be more tech specific (like [tag:.net-micro]), @Becuzz It would certainly get cleaned up eventually, just not right away.

Comment: Straight from their page:  `Post questions and see responses about this Developer Program on Stack Overflow.`  <buzz> -- Hooray for vague scope! Sorry, Microsoft, that's not how SO works...  we're not here to answer questions about some new initative.  I think I an SO representative needs to contact the [wdpforiot] guys and have a little chat.

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253849/3897316) seems to be on the same topic, which suggests that no, we should not create the tag without a valid question, and that MS shouldn't have added that link without one of their employees already being active in the tag here.

Comment: So, Microsoft is now encouraging people to post off-topic stuff on SO... sounds like the beggining of an overly-complex plan to take it over and maybe then use it to replace the MSDN forums...

Comment: Somewhat related: [Can I support my product on this site?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)

Comment: Part of me just wants to flood that tag with questions about horrible illnesses.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

My look of disapproval is strong.  Or at least members of the team are watching the hashtag also mentioned on that page.

https://twitter.com/Pete_Brown/status/563193627900645377

Suggestions to whomever reads this...

We've seen lots of companies do similar things when linking to StackOverflow and referring to it as a place to get answers about a service/product/whatever.  These references are generally very weak on scope, and people reading tend to assume that *any* related question can be asked on StackOverflow.

For example, fa_ebook used to redirect users here for, supposedly, questions about programming against their APIs.  But we'd get questions on the regular about issues with invalid API keys, questions about account statuses, questions that didn't have anything to do at all about programming.  These users would then get downvoted like crazy and have their questions closed and deleted.

This is not only disruptive to StackOverflow, but it isn't exactly the kind of experience you would want to lay on developers in your ecosystem.  Might put them off you and your products.

So, when suggesting StackOverflow as a place for developers to ask questions, you **must** be very clear about the scope of questions allowed here. Make clear statements, such as "for software development questions using our APIs".  Provide an alternative link, for example to your own forums, for all other questions.  Make the distinction between the two clear and easy for new users to understand.

And, in your case, don't try to force a new tag.  The tag you are suggesting on your page doesn't really match how we do tags here.  We like to emphasize clarity over brevity.  Or, for example, we prefer [sql-server-2014](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server-2014) over <s>[ss2k4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ss2k4)</s> (edit: sorry, misspelled that tag, should have been *[ss2k14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ss2k14)*).  I'm not sure what a good choice for your "watched" tag would be... Perhaps you should ask here on Meta for suggestions?

Comment: On the one hand, I want to point out that that last tag should probably be [tag:ss2k14] to match the long version, not [tag:ss2k4]. On the other hand, issues with typing them incorrectly are one of the reasons we use the longer tags.

Comment: At least they are listening! Kudos for getting to them on twitter.