# Is the SO link on Modern.IE officially approved?

Tags: support, internet-explorer

When you install a Windows VM from [Microsoft's Modern.IE site](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/vmhome), they have a big box on the page saying

> Need help with a bug?
>
> Tag your issue with Internet Explorer on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer)

I did that a couple months ago, and was berated for posting a non-programming question.

What is the official policy? Does Microsoft have a [support agreement](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/8ba70824-dba2-4425-bc75-247c2c29bde1/ie-web-development-support-moving-to-stack-overflow?forum=iewebdevelopment) from SO's powers that be?

Comment: They don't need SE's permission to tell people to post questions here, of course those questions will be treated no differently than any other type of question, and need to follow all of SO's guidelines for posting questions.

Comment: The official policy is to follow the rules as defined in the help center. Check out [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) for another look at this "So and so company said to ask for support on Stack Overflow" issue.

Comment: See also:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285355/can-should-we-preemptively-create-a-tag-with-no-questions-asked.  Some divisions of Microsoft don't seem to know what Stack Overflow is actually for

Comment: Also see ["IE Web Development Support Moving to Stack Overflow"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277810)

Comment: The site is targeted at developers.  Would be nice if they didn't throw their beta bugs on top of the [internet-explorer] heap.  The [modern.ie] tag would be an obvious choice.

Comment: @Hans Passant: What beta bugs? modern.IE has nothing to do with prerelease software. And "developers" in this case refers to "web developers" aka "web authors", not Windows Insiders.

Comment: Hmm, that page certainly does.  Well, good thing I didn't write the tag wiki for [modern.ie]