# Is seeding broad questions and self-answering with a form answer to create a FAQ acceptable?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, self-answer, self-promotion

I came across a user creating and self-answering a bunch of generic questions. For example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29755782/487033) (with 3 upvotes on the question and answer in 30 minutes?), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29755465/487033), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29755712/487033). They all share the same answer but a different link to the migration guide, which to me strongly resembles a link-only answer.

I found [Is it acceptable to use Stack Overflow as a Q&A for a specific product?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253852/487033) and these generally seems to fit with the guidelines Tim has written, but this still seems 'off' to me.

Comment: His intent seems noble enough, several of the other questions have no votes, so the votes may be legit.

Comment: Though it looks like all but one should be closed as duplicates... maybe.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I agree with you regarding his intent, just not sure about all these similar questions

Comment: I think the questions and answers should be merged into a single one since all of them refer to a same event that affected all those services.

Comment: I'm not too keen on a lot of those answers. They contain a whole lot of links that need to continue to work in order for people to get the proper direction.

Comment: They're all one question broken up across a dozen. Rename one to "Google API" and close the rest as duplicates

Comment: It looks like all of his questions are in this style- Starting on the 17th. They seem pretty useless to me in a lot of cases, as there's no code or anything to help in the answer, aside from links to the Google documentation. These also seem to be pretty localized to a central time and will not help future viewers in, say three years. Pretty useless questions, and probably there just to stop support questions from rolling in or something.

Comment: I guess that instead of downvoting the questions/answers, we should notify the user about this and he/she should do some merges on these questions/answers. It's not wrong to do this kind of FAQ, but I don't think is good to go replicating the same question/answer with a slight modification per case.

Comment: I left a link on one of the questions you linked so the user in question can see the discussion. It's only fair to let him see what's up and understand where the sudden negative reactions are coming from.

Comment: The user apparently works at Google, which means they don't trust seeding their own pages with the links, so they'll just dump them onto SO

Comment: He uses the words "outage," which refers to a temporary amount of time in which a service is unavailable. How would this post be likely to continue to assist people in the future? Who is looking to SO for outage information for third party services? These questions are borderline closable as-is, and the mostly link-only answers makes me think they should all be closed as off-topic.

Comment: Heh, not that I'm surprised given the thoroughness of the site, but it's nice to see that there's a circular-loop warning when trying to vote to close as a duplicate

Comment: I even saw one of the questions earlier, and thought, "Well that's a nice self-answered question, good for Google warning people."  I didn't realize he posted it *six times* though :-/  What a mess

Comment: My thought would be to nuke these questions from orbit. This is useless seeding. If a Googler can't find an answer to a question about Google on Google, then we've hit peak Google.

Comment: if these "generally seem to fit with the guidelines Tim has written" then I don't understand why it's reasonable to just ignore that and do whatever you want instead?

Comment: And you are wrong, they each have their *own* separate migration API.  Each of those separate APIs has a separate migration guide to the new version of that respective API.  And they're not just all "v1".

Comment: Original poster here, sad to see your poor reaction to what was simply an act of trying to help confused and upset developers. I also found the snark in this thread a bit unnecessary.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The questions should be merged with the master question, and all of the answers except for one deleted.

This is useless seeding; it seems like the user thought they were 'doing the right thing' by pre-empting any questions on the subject; but done in this way it's indistinguishable from noise.

I'll wait for upvotes from the community to let me know this is a consensus view; I'll also ask other Stack Overflow moderators to chime in, since merging/deleting is a destructive action.

Comment: Works for me. Go for merging.

Comment: Merging sounds good. It's not all that destructive anyway, since the titles will still be searchable.

Comment: Go forth and merge.

Comment: The aftermath looks right to me.

Comment: The problem with your "merge" is that there's no such thing as "v1 of Google APIs" as a cohesive unit.  There are many v1 Google APIs this affects and many it doesn't.  There's a specific list of these APIs that it affects and I'm not sure that can be easily extracted into the title, etc.

Comment: @EricDeFriez edit the answer to make it better.

Comment: I fundamentally disagree with merging because the questions and answers are different (N different APIs shutting down for M different reasons, linking to O different migration pages).  I think the duplication there (remember each has it's own tags, etc) is worth it here.  Trying to merge into one post is unwieldy for readers--the main people that are going to see this.  They're not going to see the dupes, just one vague answer.  Y'all made this mess, you can clean it up.  The posts are locked (duped ones), so I can't clean up myself.

Comment: @EricDeFriez Then why can't you make the announcement of APIs that are shutting down on some official Google documentation? Making vague, link-only posts here that look so similar, we have a hard time discerning them isn't going to help *anybody*. George was correct in his actions.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen there are multiple announcements on official Google docs, official Google blog posts, go check.  The titles are all pretty clearly distinct "why is _X_ API ..", "why is _Y_ API", etc.  Yes, they're similar and yes they're largely links.  The whole reason I imagine Eric Koleda posted them was because some devs *will* miss all the other things and will immediately come to stack overflow because of habit.  And for those devs they're only going to find the one they care about (because they're looking for a specific API by tag and title).  Problem with duping is that's largely lost

Comment: Original poster here, echo'ing @EricDeFriez comments, your merged question showed a lack of understanding of the problem domain and removed all the useful information I had entered. I have repaired most of your damage now, but this entire exercise could have been handled better.

Comment: @EricKoleda The best way to have handled it would have been to bring it up to meta first. "Hey, I want to make 6 different questions dealing with 6 different Google products that are all being deprecated on the same day, how should I do that?"   One of the (still present) issues with those answers is that they link to an answer, but don't provide one. I hope Google intends to support those links for ever, and never take them down.

Comment: Yes, I understand the aversion to link-only answers.  The nice thing about separate posts per API is then the answer can clearly say "API X is deprecated and you should switch to API Y <link>".  When you have N such things it becomes a bit unwieldy.  You could obviously do a table for that information but again then you lose the API name in the summary which I think is important for searchability.  Again, I'm not sure the problem with a small number of similar posts.  Users will not see all of them and be annoyed, most users are only going to see one (because they are searching by API).

Comment: Does [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327756/6304349) count as pre-empting?

Answer (score -3):

Given "a bunch" is ~5 and each of those questions represents a distinct API (that honestly may have hundreds or thousands of developers and users), and each distinct API is going to have a different migration guide and a different set of developers that are reading the post, the "duplication" seems reasonable here.  (They are not dupes, the only thing that unifies them is they are all shutting down the same day.)