# Is product support for IDEs on topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, outsourcing, product-support

From the Aptana Studio Eclipse plugin [post-download page](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/success_plugin.html):

> [Browse Discussions](http://www.aptana.com/r/aphelp)
>   The active community around Aptana Studio includes
>   [documentation](http://www.aptana.com/r/apdocs), Aptana communications and member conversations.

The documentation link is broken, the `Browse Discussions` link get redirected to the [aptana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aptana) with ~2000 questions.

For me, most questions look like product support questions. Should we have them here? Here's a couple of recent picks:

- [Does Aptana support ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901152/does-aptana-support-es6)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900632/my-aptana-3-is-incomplete-dont-have-templates
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30708185/aptana-3-cant-find-local-history
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187593/aptana-3-doesnt-ask-password-on-remote-folder

And so on.

Is it OK to have this type of questions here? Should we do something about it?

Related:

- [Is it acceptable to use Stack Overflow as a Q&A for a specific product?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product)

Comment: Does Aptana make sure that SO is not the only support forum?

Comment: @Tichodroma There's also a [bug tracker](http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD) listed on [this page](http://www.aptana.com/support.html). Does it count? Apart from that I couldn't find any other support forum (yet).

Comment: So SO is the only support option for the Free Software version. There is a separate support forum for the proprietary version. So we can narrow down the question: Is it OK for a company to offload the support for the Free Software version of their product to SO?

Comment: I think this mostly a matter of the links not being updated on the post-download page as the links on their support page work. Also, it seems as if they are presenting stackoverflow as an official product forum with no actual mention to stackoverflow.

Comment: There are a ton of questions here relating to Visual Studio, and I for one am glad that I don't need to rely on MS' own forums, or SuperUser or IDESupport.StackExchange.

Comment: Looking at the first 3 questions, they are all questions that can be answered  by a expert USER of Aptana, and given that Aptana is a tool used for programmer, they also seem to be on-topic.   (But not great questions.)     Therefore I don't think any great harm is being done.

Comment: @lexicore: A bug tracker is something else entirely. I'd say it doesn't count.

Comment: I note that the [Aptana Support](http://www.aptana.com/support.html) page lists an off-site link at Appcelerator for the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/).  They should undoubtedly fix their website if there's a broken link like that, though.  Superficially, it appears that Appcelerator is the new name for Aptana (or, alternatively, it's the old name for it — I know not which is old and which is new).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Aptana the company was acquired by Appcelerator. Appcelerator generally only refers to the company; Aptana can either refer to the company, or the IDE, Aptana Studio.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are in fact different questions in your post :

- Are linked questions on topic? YES: apart from their quality, the questions are on topic here because related to the configuration and usage of a tool used for programming.
- Is it correct for Aptana that the link for documentation is broken? NO: but I think it is not directly SO community problem - but I'll come back to that later.
- Does Aptana have another way for support? YES: you gave the link to their bug tracker.

Anyway, there are some caveats here:

- They should at least clearly state that the resource is an external one. Something like *Stack Overflow has an active community focusing to Aptana and is a great place for Q&A about this product* would be **nicer**.
- They should at least have have contacted SO team - maybe they have but I do not know; it is not explicit neither on their site nor in [aptana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aptana).
- One comment on last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30187593/3545273) suggests that the bug tracker is not really active.

IMHO on a mere formal point of view, there is nothing bad for Aptana to post a link to our great Q&A site. But as they do not clearly state that the resourse is external, and as the bug tracker does not seem very active, I won't have a definitive answer about their fairness.

But we should anyway accept questions concerning Aptana, **provided they follow our own rules**.

Comment: "are linked questions on topic ? YES : apart from their quality, the questions are on topic here because related to the configuration and usage of a tool used for programmation" - this was basically the core of my question. Broken links etc. are clearly Aptana's problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing product questions with the perpetual meta posts concerning companies that send all customers to SO and end with *Customer Support* questions posted here.

*Customer Support* questions, which concern the relationship between the vendor and customer, are off-topic here.  Examples<sup>1</sup>:

- You took money but haven't sent my license file yet.
- I got my license file but you charged my credit card twice.
- The license file you sold me is being reported as invalid.
- I want to cancel my support subscription.

On the other hand, the questions you asked are about using and troubleshooting a development tool, and therefore on-topic.  Perhaps describing them as "support" questions in legitimate, but they are not *Customer Support* questions.

Questions that are not *Customer Support* but still problematic:

- When will the new version be released?
- What features are in the new version?

These answers need to come from the vendor, but they don't have to come directly.  For technologies where roadmaps are publicly announced, such questions may be interpreted as "Has the vendor made an official statement about features in the new version?" and allowed.  In other cases where the vendor is tight-lipped, they're likely to be closed with a comment to ask the vendor directly.

This is similar to the case of "Why does my language have this rule?" questions, which are often better phrased as "What advantages does this rule provide?", since the advantages often exceed the particular case that the designer was thinking of.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that none of these examples are actually questions.  Complaints and work orders are always off-topic, even when they do involve programming and/or tools.