# Is posting a *question* to advertise your own software acceptable?

Tags: discussion, spam

I'm looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30946909/what-is-new-for-ibm-secure-gateway-1-2-0-release) that was just posted, which really doesn't *seem* like it should be allowed: the original poster "asks" for a changelog for a new version of the software he is clearly associated with (not disclosing that in the question, but it is mentioned in his profile), then immediately posts said changelog, which sounds like an advertisement (I doubt anyone not associated with the software would answer the question starting with the fact that it has "new exciting changes that we hope you will enjoy".)

However, I went to flag it, and realized, I can't think of any close reason that entirely fits. *I* would call that spam, but I know SO's rules for what spam is, is incredibly specific. Is this spam? Or something else actionable (i.e. what would I flag it as)? It really feels smelly, but I'm not sure how it would actually be closed.

Comment: It kind of sounds like it's asking for release notes, which would be an off site resource.

Comment: That question is _not_ a specific programming problem, _extremely localized,_ and in general does not fit on Stack Overflow, never mind that it's generally a bad idea to seed questions for your product.

Comment: @rene I was sort of wondering that as well. I didn't want to look *too* paranoid, though...

Comment: I think the bigger problem here is, out of curiosity, I looked at the bluemix tag... And I see a lot of off-topic questions... Like... _A lot._

Answer (score 42, accepted):

No, advertisement of your own product in any form, *including* (or even especially including) seed questions about your product is not acceptable, and is spam.

Any such questions should be destroyed with extreme prejudice (and spam flags).

Comment: So a spam flag _would_ be appropriate here? I would think if it didn't accumulate enough, mods would decline the spam flag, honestly.

Comment: @Kendra Definitely in general, and yeah, that question looks like spam to me.

Comment: I thought that if you acknowledged your association, then it wasn't spam.  Although it also seems that spam in an answer has a higher threshold than spam in a question.

Comment: @Teepeemm To a certain extent that is true. Saying: "I'm an employee that produces X and X is great!" is still spam

Comment: @Teepeemm Is the point of that contingency that people are allowed disclose affiliations that may be relevant to the question? "I work on X and I've run into trouble getting it to do Y" might look like spam if the disclosing affiliation contingency wasn't noted.

Comment: Some companies are using SO for tech support. That means they are not allowed to post their FAQs? Even if they include a disclosure and they don't post too many questions and everything else is fine? IMHO there should be a way to allow that, because such questions won't get much attention anyway if they don't get upvoted. It seems a bit odd, that one may answer his own question immediately, but not if one is related to the product.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer [This MSO FAQ post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) should help explain a bit. It's not that he answered his own question about his product, it's that it was completely off-topic for the site.

Comment: @Kendra: I agree with that. But this answer sounds more strict.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer Because seeding questions is generally frowned upon to begin with. It's bad practice. If a product you made is going to have questions asked about it, they should be asked by actual users, not by yourself to try to beat them to it. If you see know about questions that will be asked, you should have a FAQ page _on your own site_ because, as the question I linked says, _we are not support for [your favorite company.]_ For more info besides the post I linked, see [this help center article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) as well.

Comment: @Kendra: "bad practice" is very subjective. The links you provided only discuss off-topic questions. I don't understand what's the damage, if it's a well-written question and it's on-topic. We have the voting system to prevent bad quality. Thus, what's the reasoning on handling this as spam? Is there any official statement that it's forbidden?

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer Last I'm going to say on the matter here so as not to spam Bradley, but: _"if it's a well-written question and it's on-topic"_ The main problem here was _this was not an on-topic question._ It was in _no way_ on topic as defined in the help center. I personally don't agree with the spam call, honestly, but it was _not in any way on topic._ Which I stated in my first comment to you. I recall the help center article at one point covering seeding questions. But there are other questions here on Meta that hit on that, i.e. [here.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253852/2607247)

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer I would put the line a bit further. If a dev runs across a problem with their software, and wants to post a solution into an active community here, then fine. **Pretty much anything else (in terms of seeded questions) is spam**. Now, if they answer *other* people's question about their product, then that is great. This question did neither of those things, and was clearly spam in my book.

Answer (score 22):

No this is not acceptable.

However, I'm struggling to with which one of the existing close reasons to choose.

Comment: @rene - yeah, I saw. I couldn't think of anything better and as I wanted it closed I followed suit.

Comment: @rene - I'm looking into the votes so there's no need to raise another flag.

Comment: Perhaps this users answers need checking out a bit more? For example, this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30122503/1663001) is a repeat of his previous one that was deleted by a mod.

Answer (score 4):

I would not spam flag it, as it does not contain links and is not part of a large problem.   The -100 rep for posting spam seems too harsh for this.

**But I would down votes it and vote to close.**

His other (public, not deleted) posts does not look too bad to me and he does look like a real user.   *This looks like a misguided user trying to be helpful to me.*