# Merge the two tags used for Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

In Stack Overflow there exist two tags

- [azure-sqldw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sqldw)
- [azure-data-warehouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-warehouse)

which refer to the same Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse product. The MS [product page's](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-data-warehouse/) community link goes to the azure-sqldw tag page.

The azure-sqldw tag is promoted by MS, has more activity, and receives faster response times.

I propose [azure-data-warehouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-warehouse) gets merged into [azure-sqldw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-sqldw).

Comment: I don't understand where you learned that *The azure-sqldw tag is promoted by MS*? I can't find any evidence to support that claim.

Comment: Sorry to be rude, but did you look? Click on the community link on the product page https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/sql-data-warehouse/

Comment: Yes, I did but obviously not at the correct location. You're free to [edit] that in to enlighten me.

Comment: Sorry, I was unnecessarily annoyed at your comment, I should've provided evidence. Thanks for letting me know, I've edited the post.

Comment: That is an really awful way to bring visitors of that MS page to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I had the idea that folks over at MS by now know what is needed when they send users over to Stack Overflow: [Is it acceptable to use Stack Overflow as a Q&A for a specific product?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product) a simple link is not it I think.

Comment: A vast majority of the questions are answered by MS devs including myself. The tag info includes links to bug/feature requests that are off site. IMO it's very well maintained despite the single link. I can provide evidence that a majority of questions are answered by employees if you'd like. I believe people will get their questions answered faster if the tags are merged which is the driving reason behind this proposal. Multiple tags referring to the same entity is a good way of not getting help.

Comment: That is not the point. That there isn't a single step between that link and SO might bring in users that ask a question that is off-topic and then get slaughtered. That is not a good experience for the user, MS and SO. It would be better if the basic guidance what users can expect at SO and what is expected from those users, was given at the MS side of the link. Not when it is too late.

Comment: Gotcha. That's true, but off topic to the tag merge request. I'll be sure to clarify that to the content teams.

Comment: Related: [Make \[azure-sqldw\] a synonym of \[azure-sql-data-warehouse\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418953/1478931), as well as the (more recent) broader proposal here: [Microsoft Azure Collective launch and proposed tag changes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423231/1478931)

Answer (score 3):

I went ahead and re-tagged the remaining two questions. If no (new) questions get tagged with [azure-data-warehouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-data-warehouse) the tag will be gone at 03:00 UTC when the tag clean-up script runs.