# Reachout to algolia

Tags: support, outsourcing

Algolia seems to be outsourcing the Q/A to Stack Overflow.

Their [community page](https://community.algolia.com/) does not seem to indicate what is on topic for stackoverflow, just a general invite message to the [algolia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algolia)

[image]

The tag wiki is even better:

> A hosted search API.

[Jan Petr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6289838/jan-petr) seems to be a good contact.

Comment: Ah, Algolia! They're at least slightly dodgy geezers; I flagged one of their devs back in 2013 for recommending Algolia on Stack Overflow without disclosing (or even implying) his affiliation, and I had the experience as a (tiny incomeless startup) customer of theirs of their tech support telling me it was technically impossible to solve a performance problem we had except by upgrading to the $2500/month Enterprise plan... until I reluctantly said that we would have to close our account and roll our own solution, at which point they instantly solved it by changing a hidden config variable.

Comment: @MarkAmery - You publicly shamed them you could potentially become a very bad customer very fast!

Comment: Their aforementioned history of minor roguishness aside, their link to Stack Overflow doesn't seem particularly problematic to me. They're a tool pretty much entirely for use by programmers; *most* questions about Algolia will be on-topic here, and the ones that aren't will be off-topic for the same reasons that most Stack Overflow questions are off-topic - being unclear, lacking an MCVE, being too broad, etc. I don't think we'll achieve anything by demanding Algolia teach their users how to ask good Stack Overflow questions when *we* demonstrably can't teach our own users that skill.

Comment: Oh, and as an aside, if anyone *does* decide to contact them, redox is their VP of engineering and might make a better point of contact. His SO profile is https://stackoverflow.com/users/2950067/redox, his GitHub is https://github.com/redox, and his email is publicly visible on his GitHub profile.

Comment: The algolia tag info should probably be improved.

Comment: @Oriol should it? What's missing from it of actual value? Certainly it's *short* compared to the excerpt and wiki of other cloud-based thingies, like, say, http://stackoverflow.com/tags/amazon-web-services/info, but it seems to me that that's to its credit; the Algolia one conveys all the information that would be useful for a Stack Overflow user looking at the tag minus the pointless infodump that most tag descriptions have.

Comment: @MarkAmery you've already caused a reaction - enterprise is now $3,990 a month.... :0

Comment: @CalvT the $2500/month figure was from back in 2013 - chalk it up to inflation.

Comment: @MarkAmery yeah guessed that, but it makes a good comment ;)

Comment: There is already a guideline about cases like these. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product?rq=1

Comment: Is this required? I don't see why SO should reach out as long as there is no problem. So are there often questions posted in the [tag:algolia] tag that are off-topic/bad quality/too broad/... ?

Comment: Hey @MarkAmery, happy to have a chat if Josh's answer is not enough. We're really not trying to "outsource" Q/A here :/ As Josh mentioned, off-topic questions are redirected to our Discourse instance. Also, I'm used to answer A LOT of those SO questions as my profile confirms.

Comment: No need to try and persuade me, @redox - while I have [some unrelated beef](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341766/reachout-to-algolia#comment433923_341766) with you guys from back in 2013, I thought that the particular criticism of you that this question is about (about you "outsourcing" QA here) was silly and unwarranted, and [said so in my second comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341766/reachout-to-algolia#comment433927_341766), which got more upvotes than the question itself. Community consensus seems to be that you're doing nothing wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Josh here, I'm a Developer Advocate at Algolia. We love SO, get a lot of value from this community, and want to make sure that we're following all of the guidelines. I have edited the tag wiki (pending peer review) to direct users to [discourse.algolia.com](https://discourse.algolia.com/) if their question is off-topic for SO.

We have a new version of our community site in the works, and that will show users both a link to SO and a link to our Discourse, with clear instructions on what to post where. We will do the same with the help links inside of our dashboard. We set up our Discourse about two months ago as a place to gather our community and to help reduce the number of off-topic posts that SO moderators have to deal with. Once that is released, I'll post back here, as I would love your feedback on whether our instructions are clear enough.

In the meantime I'm here to listen if you have any other suggestions or feedback.