# Is it OK if the documentation of an open source project links to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have to be careful with my wording, because I don't want to openly denounce anybody. In fact I don't have a definite opinion on the issue, but I am interested if there is an official Stack Overflow policy.

Yesterday I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45982517/meshlab-feature-function-to-select-triangles-and-highlight-them-in-the-ascii-st?noredirect=1#comment78969454_45982517). It is a about an open source project called MeshLab. The question is about stuff that I would expect to find in the docs of the project. However, on [their support page](http://www.meshlab.net/#support) there is a questions and forum section that states:

> Questions and Forum
>
> For question, clarifications and any kind of
>   doubts about MeshLab and how to get the best result with the various
>   filters, use stackoverflow. Be specific, and tag your questions with
>   MeshLab.

And next to this text there are two buttons with links to the Stack Overflow search (labeled "Search Question") and for asking a question on Stack Overflow ("Ask Question").

As I said above, I don't know if there is anything wrong with this, but it made me curious on whether there is a policy for external sites linking to Stack Overflow. I find it at least questionable, because:

- On their page one could get the impression that the links lead to some official MeshLab forum, which is not the case.
- Shouldn't Stack Overflow be for questions that cannot be answered by reading the documentation? To me it seems like MeshLab is encouraging their users to ask on Stack Overflow as their first source of information, instead of first trying to get information somewhere else.
- Most of the questions tagged as MeshLab don't have answers, which suggests that there isn't much MeshLab support on Stack Overflow.

...of course there are also positive aspects, e.g. Stack Overflow is indeed a good place for questions and answers and by guiding their users to Stack Overflow they make sure that questions and answers will be easily available.

Is there a consensus on what is OK and what isn't when linking to Stack Overflow?

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product

Comment: also the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Comment: Stack Overflow can't dictate what projects and companies do or say. We can *help them with guidance* on how to best point to Stack Overflow, that's all.

Comment: @rene the answer in that question already cleared all my doubts

Comment: @MartijnPieters of course SO cant dictate, but it can have an opinion on the matter

Comment: @rene should I edit the question to remove any reference to meshlab? I wasnt really sure, and didnt want to make a point on meshlab, but this was just what lead me to the more general question

Comment: I have no issue with it  ...