# Reachout to DotNetBrowser

Tags: support, outsourcing

In the vein of [Is it acceptable to use Stack Overflow as a Q&A for a specific product?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product), We need to have someone reach out to [dotnetbrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnetbrowser).

I've seen <s>some</s> many posts answered directly by their engineers. They are treating Stack Overflow as their primary community site.

On this page https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/home:

> Check Stack Overflow community forum to see 
>                         how other developers solved similar issues 
>                         or post your own question using #dotnetbrowser tag.

Also their navigation has a Questions link which links to the tag page.

Here's a few low quality posts:

- [How to handle authorization with DotNetBrowser user control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380842/how-to-handle-authorization-with-dotnetbrowser-user-control/47386176#47386176) - Answered by their own team
- [Dotnetbrowser error license](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48269823/dotnetbrowser-error-license) - Sounds like a support request
- [How do I handle this DotNetBrowser LicenseException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48273471/how-do-i-handle-this-dotnetbrowser-licenseexception#comment83531277_48273471) - This comment is telling
- [Customize Dropdown pop-ups in DotNetBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228472/customize-dropdown-pop-ups-in-dotnetbrowser)
- [How to install Open-Source license #dotnetbrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48067839/how-to-install-open-source-license-dotnetbrowser) - Another support request
- [dotnetbrowser click event position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48042413/dotnetbrowser-click-event-position) - no clear effort by OP, answered by team

This practice is strongly discouraged and should be corrected before we get an influx of support tickets.

Related by the same company:

- [jxbrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jxbrowser)

  - [JxBrowser speculative execution side channel Spectre vulnerability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48197518/jxbrowser-speculative-execution-side-channel-spectre-vulnerability) - Off topic, answered by own team. Really should be directly to the company.
- [jxmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jxmaps)

They appear to have their own forums on other products, but not the ones that have special tags.

Comment: Have you observed any actual influx of LQ / support questions on that tag? Do they represent a worrying portion of the questions asked? And in any case, you can still reach out to them yourself to tell them about minding our rules and scope and reminding their customers to do it.

Comment: @PaulStenne the most recent in the [dotnetbrowser] tag are troubling. hence my post. even tho i'm a high rep user, it generally is best for a mod or stack employee to doing the negotation.

Comment: @annadolbina if you work for dot net browser (from your profile [link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4977706/anna-dolbina), your top tags, and your most recent answers), do you have anything to comment about this post?

Comment: Thanks @DanielA.White. I have also ping VladyslavTsvek on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143495/failed-to-create-browser-error-access-denied), and hopefully he will give a reply. And I ping Anna on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380842/how-to-handle-authorization-with-dotnetbrowser-user-control/47386176#47386176

Comment: It seems like the technology is primarily for use by developers. Are the questions off topic? Can you edit some examples in if so?

Comment: I'd also like to see some examples of actual problems. At least linked ones ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143495/failed-to-create-browser-error-access-denied), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380842/how-to-handle-authorization-with-dotnetbrowser-user-control)) seem to me perfectly on-topic questions.

Comment: @eis the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380842/how-to-handle-authorization-with-dotnetbrowser-user-control/47386176#47386176 is a link only answer. If the engineers are only going to reply with links to their help pages they can stick to their own forums

Comment: @Tschallacka I thought we were talking about *questions* being appropriate for this site?

Comment: @DanielA.White Could you please clarify what Stack Exchange terms (https://stackexchange.com/legal) are violated when .NET developers use StackOverflow to post their programming-related questions about different aspects of the .NET library (DotNetBrowser) usage?

Comment: @Vladimir its not a question of the TOS, its a question of the community guidelines.

Comment: @jpmc26 i've added samples.

Comment: @eis its a combination of questions and answers. i've had to flag an answer that was a non-disclosed spam.

Comment: The first example you posted has just been updated by the support engineer who answered it. So it does now look like a decent answer. It seems they're going to be receptive to our requests.

Comment: @DavidG i dont want them to be the only ones to be able to answer the questions

Comment: Who said they were the only ones? I'm just pointing out that 1 answer has been updated due to this meta post.

Comment: @DavidG in my quick scan, most of the questions were answered by their team

Comment: That could mean it's a new product, has poor documentation or the support staff are being given dedicated time to help. AFAIK there's no rule here that says it's bad that questions tend to be answered by official support staff.

Comment: @DavidG https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product

Comment: @DavidG quite simply they have a link in their main navigation to stackoverflow. it seems like the want to drive the community here, not to their site.

Comment: Yes, I agree they need to change their website to clarify what Stack Overflow is used for. But in reference the the post you just linked, the answer there states this can work out well if certain things are in place, and it looks like they're almost there on that regard. All I was trying to point out was that they look like they will be receptive to requests.

Comment: The text needs to change from `Check Stack Overflow community forum to see how other developers solved similar issues or post your own question using #dotnetbrowser tag.` to something like `Check out our Stack Overflow #dotnetbrowser tag to see how other developers solved similar issues, or post your own question. Please note that this channel should not be used for general support queries.`.

Comment: It adds an interesting way to increase your own rep if you sell any form of dev tool if you tell everyone to come here and you get all your rep answering questions about your own stuff