# Why were these 31 questions about [intersystems-iris] deleted? Was it because they were posted in another site simultaneously?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, cross-posting

I'm a community manager on https://community.intersystems.com/

Some time ago I asked a user in our site (https://community.intersystems.com/user/muhammad-waseem) to repost several questions here on SO, at the same time that the questions were posted over there. Which he did, using [this account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16757060/muhammad-waseem).

Two weeks ago Stack Overflow moderators deleted 31 of these questions.

Is cross-posting prohibited, or why were these questions deleted?

Comment: Depends on the exact posts, were they plagiarised? Did they reference the original appropriately? Were the posts on topic in the first place? Etc.

Comment: > Does this answer your question? Posting a question that is coming from another domain-specific forum.- it doesn't. Questions were published in both places simultaneously, to expand the audience.

Comment: *"Questions were published in both places simultaneously, to expand the audience."* - I cant think of any reason to do that other than urgent desperation, in which case, you should think about better planning in your day to day tasks so you don't need to ask in multiple places at the same time to maximise answer chance.

Comment: >Depends on the exact posts, were they plagiarised? Did they reference the original appropriately? Were the posts on topic in the first place? Etc. – 
It depends what is original. Some questions were posted first on SO then on another forum or vice-versa. The time difference of publications are minutes at most. The same author at both places

Comment: >It depends on the details. Was the author reposting the questions, or was someone else doing it? These "other forums", were they outside the SE network? Why were the questions reposted in such great numbers? - It was the author who reposted. Another forum is a standalone outside of SE network

Comment: @Nick, I'm a community manager of another forum, and I asked the developer to publish on another forum and on SO too simultaneously. The intention is to increase the presence of the technology on SO too and get the SO audience attention. It's a bit "artificial" approach, that's why I want to be sure that it is blessed. Or 100% prohibited.

Comment: *"increase the presence of the technology on SO too and get the SO audience attention"* - That sounds like spam. As yivi said, can you show us some example posts so we have a better idea exactly what happened?

Comment: @yivi - questions were published by this author https://stackoverflow.com/users/16757060/muhammad-waseem. Here is the profile of the author in another forum: https://community.intersystems.com/user/muhammad-waseem. He had 30+ published on SO too with this tag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersystems-iris

Comment: I consider it rude and abusive to conspire to have multiple sets of users wasting time on the same questions in parallel.  Yes, that is somewhat inevitable, even when posting on one site, but such cross-posting, especially in bulk, says to me: 'I want answers ASAP and I don't care about anyone else's time, as long my own is not wasted'.

Comment: Yup, that's still not enough, because we can't see the actual questions. Only a moderator can see deleted posts (the author or a user with more than 10k could, but only if they had the links).

Comment: Most of the posts on their intersystems profile suggests they asked dozens of non-programming or non-specific questions. This is a programming site expecting questions which will help future users, and those questions would be off topic

Comment: @MartinJames, I'm the community manager of another forum that is pretty vivid. I want to increase the activity around the tag that relates to the technology our company produces https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersystems-iris . And as a community manager I asked some developers from our forum to duplicate some of their NEW questions that are wide enough in both places. This is an intentional cross-posting. Is it OK?

Comment: It's not great, @Evgeny. But again, it depends on the details. It can be bad, it can be acceptable. Simply "repost all questions" is clearly a very bad strategy. Since we cannot see the actual questions, can't see if they posted answers here as well, if they were adequately on-topic, if they didn't look like spam, etc; we are simply left guessing.

Comment: @yivi we can't see cause they were deleted by moderators. E.g. this one https://community.intersystems.com/post/how-separate-namespace-globals-and-routines-databases was cross-posted on SO and DC(our forum) both.

Comment: @yivi. Maybe cross-posting is not great. But what is the acceptable strategy for a community manager like myself to increase the audience on SO? To say active contributors of our forum to abandon the forum in favor of SO? This is why I developers in our technology to ask upon a good will in both places simultaneously. 2 or three do that. One was pretty active with 30+ questions - and now they are all deleted on SO. So I wonder if this is a blessed way to go. And if there is a better approach if it exists. I'm sure I'm not alone in such intention.

Comment: 31 questions are a lot of questions and a user asking those questions for the _same_ tag (and it seems they have only 1 question that is not deleted, again for this tag) belonging to your company would seem very suspicious, and might have gotten flagged by someone as "excessive promotion".

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat he is not in our company, he just uses the technology and contributes to the forum I manage. The question was not undeleted - it is a new one he contributed after the moderation action.

Comment: Might be related/useful: [Can I support my product on this site?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) and [Is it ever acceptable to seed Stack Overflow with product-related questions (and answers)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374465/2821954)

Comment: @EvgenyShvarov by undeleted I meant "not deleted". Also have a look at this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260641/14991864) specifically the points about "Excessive/Improper Promotion". A user may get mistaken to be affiliated with you if the only thing they post about is your company.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I agree that the organic way is the best way.  And there some organic questions but very few. But developers tend to ask questions about the technology, right? ) This is why we have SO. And the developers of our community do ask questions on our forum, quite a lot. I want to expand the audience and make SO users to see our technology. I can close our Q&A forum and ask all the community contribute to SO. This will be 100% organic, but this is a bit radical, isn't it? What is the better approach in such a situation? What do you think?

Comment: From what we see, plenty of the questions in your forum would not be on-topic or appropriate on this site, which is not a forum. So "closing your site" just to drive the traffic to SO would not necessarily work great for your community.

Comment: @AndrewT., yes it's related, but it's clear that seeding is not an option. This is 100% inorganic. What I try to do is organic cross-posting if you may )

Comment: @yivi, right. That's why Muhammad published on the SO about 30 out of his 44 questions on our forum. Some are very specific to the technology. But some are quite broad and relevant to the SO audience too.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, yes indeed. Moderators stated that it is me, but I described that it wasn't me and they agreed then but posts are still deleted after two weeks of the moderation action with no follow-up. So that's why I raised the discussion what are the cross-posting details and if I still can ask developers from our forum to cross-post on both places questions that are relevant to the SO too.

Comment: The thing is is, you are thinking of SO with a "community manager that wants to promote a product" mindset. That's not awesome, and it's very likely that will end up badly, because it goes at cross-purposes with what we want for the site. (Also, it's unlikely to work; you are putting the cart before the horses: things to not get better known because they exist on SO, obscure tags will remain obscure unless something else **outside of SO** make them less obscure).

Comment: @yivi, I agree and disagree. Before I started the community management of the forum it was standalone and obscure, now it's vivid and helpful. So can be done with SO tag if the developers that want to ask questions exist. But they ask questions in the place they got used too. There are numerous general-purpose Q&A sites like SO but devs come here because the best audience is here - and there were times when SO was obscure, right? So for me the question is whether I need to shut down our Q&A forum in favor of the SO tag or are there any options of helpful contributions if I want both?

Comment: Since those questions are also on your forum, edit your question to add some links to the copies of the 30 deleted questions from there. Otherwise how can we comment on the suitability or not of the questions.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I see. But if the question crafted for SO be reposted on another forum, will the question be deleted then on SO?

Comment: You want blanket answers and we keep saying: it depends on the details.

Comment: @RobertLongson, all the 30 questions of such were deleted. All of them were cross-posts.

Comment: They were deleted on **your** forum too? Why was that?

Comment: @RobertLongson, they were not deleted on our forum. Here they are: https://community.intersystems.com/user/234746/posts?page=1

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, thanks! Could you please point me to the rules of the proper attribution of such cross-posting contribution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which of those 44 posts were deleted? Let's not try to make us do all the work to identify them. However the first few seem very poor quality i.e. they are write my code for me questions that do not do well here. I can imagine they would be downvoted and roomba deleted without any moderator intervention at all.

Comment: @yivi. Some developers don't do 100% organic, not cross-posting contribution because the tag is obscure. It's a chicken-egg problem: "why should I ask even I have a question if nobody is here?" This is what they think and they are right. So some presence should appear first. This is my intention.

Comment: @RobertLongson, don't see deleted questions of some SO contributor, how can I? I remember one or two that I answered on the SO, here is at least one of them. https://community.intersystems.com/post/how-separate-namespace-globals-and-routines-databases

Comment: Thanks to all the commenters! To resume if questions are related to the SO audience, if the author is the same, and if the post is properly attributed questions can be cross-posted with the SO and another outside with the hope it will not be deleted then on the SO but no guarantee.

Comment: And most importantly the questions need to be high quality. None of the 40 or so questions you linked in your forum would seem to qualify on that front.

Comment: "*There are numerous general-purpose Q&A sites like SO*" just want to make sure that SO is not a general-purpose Q&A site, but it's a Q&A site specifically for practical programming (within the scope that has been defined by this community). SO is just a part of [the bigger SE network that has 150+ Q&A sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: @RobertLongson. I agree that quality is important. As I mentioned above moderators suspected sockpuppets activity with this with me as an actor. And once we figured that it is not they still left these questions deleted. I hope they will change the reason to the "low quality" statement and deliver this to the author hopefully for all the 31 question deleted.

Comment: Wouldn’t change the fact the questions would remain deleted.  The user was likely deleted, I would argue asking 30+ extremely low quality questions, is enough reason to delete the user. Users have been suspended for asking less than 30 low quality questions

Comment: also related: [Is there any automation to detect/stop shill behaviour?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300810/839601) and [Should I ask questions that have been answered on other Q&A sites?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251469/839601)

Comment: Here is a list of links to deleted question in that tag; https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1455162 / cc @RobertLongson

Comment: @gnat - this is not my question here. The question is about cross-posting on different forums as you can see. But the link is helpful though, thanks.

Comment: Also, I'm curious for those who vote negatively - what's wrong with the question?

Comment: @EvgenyShvarov I think if you compare your initial meta-question to the SO-questions cited below, you should – hopefully – see some similarities. The new variant is worded better, but it's still missing key information. If people are required to go the extra mile to dig up things because a question author did not bother providing them, that's not exactly a good situation.

Comment: you asked two questions: "is cross-posting prohibited" and "why were these questions deleted". Second question is answered in my suggestion [above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411165/why-were-these-31-questions-about-intersystems-iris-deleted-was-it-because-th?noredirect=1#comment863706_411165) - question were deleted because of targeted voting, not because of cross-posting. Your first question is answered by a second link in my next comment - cross-posting is not prohibited, especially if poster is fothright about this

Comment: @MisterMiyagi  - looked through the revisions:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/411165/revisions The questions were deleted and I hadn't the link to the deleted user's profile and his posts. I think the question was OK for the information i got at the moment of posting. But thanks for your comment.

Comment: @gnat Ah! Agree) That's bad practice - hate this too ) thanks )

Comment: @gnat thanks for the answers on both. Questions were deleted because of the low quality

Answer (score 17):

##### Let's go through [some of the questions](https://community.intersystems.com/user/234746/posts?page=1) then...

> Hi

We [don't want fluff like Hi](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) in questions. We're a Q&A site, not a chat.

> Upon creating namespace I selected same database for both Globals and Routines. How can I separate both the databases. Please note that I already have data and code saved in database.

How did you create a namespace? This question seems to be lacking in the details required for us to recreate it. Is this a programming question at all or some question about general user facing software e.g. a GUI that doesn't involve programming and is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

> Thanks

See the Hi problem above.

##### Let's try another (this one is similar to many others) ...

> Hi,

Oh dear, they all start and end like this.

> How to write code in table trigger to send SMS upon any modification on particular column?

OK, where are you stuck? What code have you written so far? Can you write a trigger but not send SMS? Can you send SMS outside of a table trigger? This seems to be a write my code question, constructed for the purpose of documenting some system. Your system needs better documentation about triggers and SMS I guess.

> Thanks

These kind of questions would likely be downvoted and closed as lacking in details, it's unlikely therefore they would be answered, and once downvoted there's a [Roomba process](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) that deletes such questions all without moderator intervention at all.

Your other problem may be that if [one account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16757060/muhammad-waseem) is asking all the questions and you are answering them all then that other user is looking and acting like your [sock puppet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sock-puppets), particularly if he's upvoting all your answers. We don't allow voting targetted at users so that will get the both of you in trouble.

Comment: I agree that the quality of the questions and the quality of our platform'ss documentation have room for enhancement. And this relates to the majority of systems and people's skills. But I think this was not the reason for the deletion, right?

Comment: I'm telling you exactly the opposite, that it **was** the reason for deletion. Poor quality questions should and will be deleted.

Comment: Got you, @RobertLongson. Fair enough. I hope the reason for the deletion was delivered to the author.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov probably got caught as a potential voting ring instead, if the participants of this tag were quite few and upvoting each other...

Comment: @AndrewT., I did upvote the questions and answers within the tag that I consider meaningful. Apologies if it is not appropriate activity.

Comment: @RobertLongson, about Sockpuppet - that could be the case but it didn't. The issue with Muhammad's questions on the SO was that almost nobody answered it and it stayed orphaned. I tried to answer those that I had a knowledge of by myself. Yes, I'm the developer too besides community manager. So it didn't. You can check, I answered maybe ten out of 30 somehow. Not all of them were considered as accepted answers.

Answer (score 11):

> Is cross-posting prohibited, or why were these questions deleted?

We sent you a mod message on Aug 26 that explained that we deleted your coworker's account because it was acting like a sockpuppet: he posted questions, you posted answers and then you shared votes between the accounts. All of that is covered by [our sockpuppet rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388985/2370483).

> "Voting" includes:
>
> - voting on posts from your main account with your alternate account(s) and vice versa.
> - accepting the other account's answer on your post.

That it was a coworker is irrelevant. The actions were inappropriate (we consider that voting fraud) and we told you as such.

> The offending accounts will be removed and the votes invalidated.

You seemed to understand that in your response

> Ah. I see what's going on now. You've deleted all the questions from Muhammad Waseem. Muhammad is a real person, the developer from our partner in the Middle East. here is Muhammad's profile on the InterSystems Developer Community.
> I asked InterSystems developers to contribute to Stackoverflow in a way to raise questions on our Developer Forum and on Stackoverflow both. And he was answered on our forum by different developers, but on StackOverflow, it was me in the majority of cases who answered him when I knew the answer.
> (snip)
> And as for the case of Muhammad Waseem's account, this is not a sockpuppets case at all, but the case of the same questions on both forums.

A moderator responded to your concerns. Everything else Robert Longson said about quality holds as well. None of the questions met SO quality standards. You're not the only person to run afoul of this, but it's important that if you're going to do this in the future that

1. Have the same account post both the question and the answer (there's a checkbox to do that in the ask page) and **do not have coworkers upvote it**. Coworker voting will show up eventually and we will reverse the votes and/or delete the account as a sockpuppet
2. The questions need to be far more than just simple forum questions. It's worth reading [this post about the Q&A format differences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/362474/2370483). In particular

   > We want clear focused questions: if we don't allow 2 pages of back-and-forth discussion to draw out the scenario, it better be in the question or everyone's just gonna have to guess.
3. Your questions really need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Overly simplistic "How do I do this?" questions have a place, but the community prefers a concrete example to work with. Asking a lot of them over and over is likely to get you flagged as well.

Comment: >We sent you a mod message on Aug 26 that explained that we deleted your coworker's account because it was acting like a sockpuppet: he posted questions, you posted answers, and then you shared votes between the accounts. All of that is covered by our sockpuppet rules.
he is not my coworker. He is just a member of a community. I don't know him in person and he is very new to InterSystems Community too.

Comment: Moderator never told about the quality. If this is the reason to delete questions could you please deliver that to the deleted member?

Comment: As you can see there is no sockpuppet case here.

Comment: I just want to be sure that you guys don't delete the user and ALL his posts for one reason. And once it is not the case you get another reason for the "bad quality" expanded to all the posts of the user. Anyway, I'm grateful for the time you spent on this and the explanations you did. Thank you!

Comment: The problem with socks is we get the whole "That's a different person" story a lot. Maybe they are a different person, but if they're doing a lot of sock voting, we err on the side of them being a sock (voting isn't the only thing we look at, but it's a big one). And you hadn't shared just a few votes either. I should note that he's re-created his account (that's the one you linked to) and he is able to post (his single question was poor quality so it's been closed and deleted).

Comment: As a community manager, a agree. We fight this issue in our community too - we have the problem with votes and fake accounts. But the scale is not comparable of course.

Comment: In some ways, this spares him the headache of a question ban (which mods can't do anything about). The original questions are not salvageable. I get that it seems heavy-handed, but we do actively try to let folks know about community standards *before* they post anything.

Comment: I see. Anyway, thanks to all - I got the answer for my question: Cross-posting is not welcomed but allowed if the quality of questions is high, the author is the same, there are no socks, and cross-posting is properly mentioned.