# We are getting a lot of questions about a new family of programming languages we are helping make. Can we direct those here?

Tags: discussion

Our non-profit open source research group (https://lab.treenotation.org/) is getting lots of repeated questions about our work on Tree Notation.

Instead of constantly answering those questions on [Reddit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit), [Hacker News](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hacker_News), our web page, etc., can we repost them on Stack Overflow and tag them "treenotation"? That way people can upvote/downvote answers, contribute comments, etc., and there would start to be a common place to have all these common questions.

I don't want it to come across as self-promoting and just wanted to ask for guidance before pursuing this.

Example discussions: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=20856525, https://lobste.rs/s/fyacbq/rfc_treebase.

Comment: From a glance, those questions don't really seem like a good fit for SO. They seem to be more "discussions" than objective Q/A...

Comment: Make sure to read [the help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) and [the faq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253849/215552).

Comment: Maybe SO for teams?

Comment: Are these questions about programming (as defined in the help center)? If yes I see no problem.

Comment: Thank you @HereticMonkey! Exact guidance that I was looking for.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Questions about the development of a programming language can only be reliably answered if the developers are regularly around to answer them, or public documentation and discussions are available online for reference and citation.

But in this case, as the language itself is in its formative stage and far from mature, and answers to questions about how it works are subject to rapid and significant changes, I don't think Stack Overflow is suitable for questions about its development, or even its usage just yet. GitHub Issues may be a better fit — but I'm only tossing it out there because a number of web standards working groups also use it for Q&A, discussion, and bikeshedding for web standards to great effect.

Comment: Great points! It does seem too early perhaps for SO. Thanks @BoltClock! This coupled with the link provided by @HereticMonkey are the answers I needed https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support