# How can I apply for the creating for the new tags?

Tags: support, tags

I know that it's required 1500 points of reputation to create the new tag. I don't have enough reputation to create the new tags, but I want to support my libraries [@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/yamato_daiwa-es_extensions), [@yamato-daiwa/frontend](https://github.com/TokugawaTakeshi/yamato_daiwa-frontend) and more in the future. If appropriate tags will be created, I can subscribe for the new questions and answer to them.

Can I apply for the creating of the new tags?

Comment: Via the [*"When is it appropriate to create a tag, and how does it work?
"* FAQ post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252944/when-is-it-appropriate-to-create-a-tag-and-how-does-it-work), you're in the right place– this is the place to ask! In line with that FAQ, please provide 1) a few existing questions where the tag would be appropriate, 2) confirmation that the topic is on-topic here on SO, 3) an example wiki excerpt and description, and 4) a good tag name.

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate of the FAQ that @zcoop98 mentioned. That is the answer to your question; basically, yes, you can request that a new tag be created. This very site is where you would make that request. What you have here is not quite sufficient to constitute a request. You can either [edit] this post and add the required justifications (then I can re-open this), or you can post a second question.

Comment: Please note the product support guidance: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product?noredirect=1&lq=1 that guidance applies to non-commercial endeavors as well. The developers that use your library are "customers"

Comment: Naming is hard, but perhaps change the names to something less generic than "ES extensions" and "frontend"? If nothing else, for SEO reasons. *Yamato TypeScript Utilities* (YTU)?

Comment: @Peter Mortensen, Thank you for the comment. The matter is must tag be even with library official name or no.