# What's the best way to allow Public Q&A for a platform-specific API? A tag on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, tags

I'm a developer at [Agworld](https://www.agworld.com/us/) which is one of the main digital platforms for the agricultural industry. We have tens of API partners that write to our public API ([documentation here](https://us.agworld.co/api/docs)).

We want to allow them to be able to post questions to a Stack Exchange platform publicly that we can answer for them so that other API developers can learn from their questions. What's the best way to achieve this?

My current thought is to create a new tag on Stack Overflow called [agworld-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agworld-api), and recommending API partners to post questions there with that tag, and our internal teams (and other external devs) can subscribe to that tag to answer them. Is this appropriate, and the best way to achieve the outcome? Or is there a better or more appropriate alternative?

*Aside:* We already pay for a Stack Overflow for Teams account for Agworld internally which we love, although it doesn't seem like that could work for this purpose because (a) we don't want API partners seeing internal questions and (b) they would need to register separate private accounts with us (unscalable), rather than just using their existing public Stack Overflow accounts.

Comment: Also, related help center: [Can I support my product on this site?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support)

Comment: @OlegValter yes, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253852/1852005 answers the question well, thank you. I read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252945/1852005, but that product-specific Qu. is more relevant in this case.

Comment: NP - it contains everything one needs to know about setting up for maintaining a Q&A for a specific product/API. Follow the guidelines there, and everything should be a-ok :)

Comment: stwr667 Note that Stack Overflow has [sponsored tags](https://stackoverflow.com/advertising/solutions#tag) where you can pay to add an icon beside the tag, such as is done for [google-app-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-app-engine). This is an alternative to, or works in conjunction with, [collectives](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives).